# Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, pixelated

I have the following LaTeX-document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Sample}
\author{Litb}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
 This is a report about my praxis phase at the company foo bar which I enjoyed.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Much to my frustration, compiling with `pdflatex` creates a document with Bitmap-fonts. The reader's font-list shows that it uses Type3 fonts.

If I remove the `fontenc` loading, then I get a PDF using vector-fonts, but I heard that I should keep it, for having native German Umlauts working.

Does anyone know how I can get vector fonts with T1, and why it keeps using bitmap fonts if I have that package-load line in it?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The standard Computer Modern fonts are in OT1 encoding, so when you request T1 font encoding bitmap fonts are used. Install the package [`cm-super`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) to get Computer Modern fonts with T1 support.

There's no change in your document needed. Just install `cm-super` using the MiKTeX Package Manager or the TeX Live Manager. The package manager will update the font map files for you. Then recompile.

- [cm-super MiKTeX package information](http://miktex.org/packages/cm-super)
- [Installing with TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html)
- [cm-super for download on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super)
- [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/de/squeeze/cm-super), works on Debian and Ubuntu for example with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cm-super
  ```

While this is a solution for fixing the default look, consider using a T1 supporting font, such as Latin Modern, which has been designed as successor to Computer Modern and thus is very similar but intended to be better. For the decision, this may help:

- [Latin Modern vs. cm-super](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super)

And for trying yourself, just add:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: You could try updating the font map files by `sudo updmap-sys --syncwithtrees`, see http://linux.die.net/man/1/updmap-sys.

Comment: @Stefan ohh i see now. I found the cause of the issue: The updmap's config file was were broken - apparently there was an entry of a mapfile "ams-bsr-interpolated.map" that wasn't existing at all. I first tried to run `updmap --syncwithtrees` but then i found i need to use `updmap-sys` since it was the global configfile that was broken. Now it works like a charm, and with the latin-modern fonts, *all* fonts referenced in my other files are vector fonts.

Comment: Haha yes the problem was with the map files. Thanks again :) Finally i can use the microtype package =)

Comment: I compiled a simple document with the lmodern package. If i open the pdf in illustrator and look at the font, its all LMRoman10 Regular, LMMathItalic10 Bold, LMMathSymbols10 Regular  - so i wonder if thats really is vector fonts? as of why are the font size included in the font ?

Answer (score 20):

The default fonts for T1 are bitmaps, as has been mentioned, and the most straightforward solution is to use cm-super, like Stefan said.  Alternatively, you could use the Latin Modern fonts (package lmodern).  It is based on Computer Modern and supports a *lot* of languages written in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: Using latin-modern fonts work nicely. I wonder what's up with cm-super not working on my system. I have installed it (i have a couple of cm-super files on my system including `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc`. I have no idea what could be wrong

Comment: That's not the font, it's an encoding file.  And since it's not straightforward to know which font file is the default, you're really better off with Latin Modern.

Comment: Ohh i see now. I guess i will use latin modern in my future files. It looks sweet :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
```

Both cm-super and lmodern used look worse than the real type 1 Computer Modern fonts (depending on your PDF viewer, zoom level, etc.). The `ae` package is an ugly kludge, but at least it *looks* ok, and you will get vectors instead of bitmaps. Copy-paste is another story...

Comment: Could you give an example where lmodern looks worse than computer modern?

Comment: Here is a pair of old screenshots: [ae](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/latex/fontit/kpdf-160-ae.png), [lmodern](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/latex/fontit/kpdf-160-lmodern.png). I'm sure both lmodern *and* PDF viewers have improved since then, but at least it serves as a good example that one shouldn't assume that lmodern always looks as good as CM.

Comment: Well, compiling the text now produces identical output, except by the positioning of the umlauts ¨; where lmodern and CM agree and ae do not.

Comment: What are these "real type 1 Computer Modern fonts" you speak of? Computer Modern was originally done in METAFONT, which apparently cannot be accurately rendered in Type 1 outlines. According to [MetaFog: Converting METAFONT Shapes to Contours](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:bhII2fBbcroJ:www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb16-3/tb48kinc.pdf), this is because the METAFONT outlines would have to be described using sopmething like a 6th degree polynomial whereas Type1 only uses 3rd degree polynomials

Comment: @SamB: See http://www.ams.org/publications/type1-fonts – yes, they are reimplementations of the *original* CM fonts, but they are very high-quality reimplementations, with proper hinting.

Comment: @Jukka: oh, I forgot about that version, even though I believe it's the one I'm using now. I wonder why CM-super doesn't use these "BlueSky" fonts for the basic stuff?

Comment: On my system, the output produced by `ae` is slightly ***worse*** kerning-wise than that produced by default (with `cm-super` installed) (which is virtually identical to `lmodern`).

Comment: @JukkaSuomela The files are 404. Maybe, you can add screenshots to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

As for explicitly setting fontenc, I usually just set an inputenc, and write away. On TeXlive 2008 and 2009, this has been doing exactly what I expect so far; and I use both Swedish and German umlauts.

Comment: Breaks hyphenation.

Comment: More specifically, if you just need some Swedish or German umlauts occasionally in an English text, it's ok, but if you are writing in Swedish or German (i.e., lots of words with umlauts), you will need to change fontenc to get the correct hyphenation. For more details, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725/why-words-with-accented-characters-cant-be-automatic-hyphenated-with-the-default

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the font (e.g. defined by a template).

Install cm-super as written earlier: (do not edit the tex-file)
[image: MikTeX cm-super]

Comment: Fyi, no \usepackage{lmodern} needed if cm-super is installed