# Configure LaTeX to use lmodern for T1 by default?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, latin-modern

Like those contributing to the discussion of [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically), I have also found the automatic use of bitmap fonts very annoying as the output is really horrible. My question is:

How to configure LaTeX (TeX Live) so that if T1 is used it uses `lmodern` by default and if `lmodern` isn't available don't try to generate bitmap fonts?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to configure your Latex environment so that you will get a non-standard output; sooner or later, you will have troubles. Why not simply add a short preample that does what you want? You can \input your preamble if you don't want to see it in every Latex document that you edit.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is something needs care. But I think it is useful for people who like to mess with computers, particularly in the case of incomplete installation of TeX live or the like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the font configuration by modifying fonttext.cfg and fontmath.cfg, see *Configuration Options for LaTeX 2e*. You can find this document with

```
texdoc cfgguide
```

Hovever, it is not recommended to change the font setup. Here is a quote from fontdef.dtx:

```
% \section{Customization}
%
% You are not allowed to change this source file!  If you want to
% change the default encodings and/or the font shape groups preloaded
% you should should create a copy of \texttt{fonttext.ltx}
% under the name \texttt{fonttext.cfg} and change this copy. If
% \LaTeXe{} finds a file of this name it will use it, otherwise it
% uses the standard file which is \texttt{fontdef.ltx}.
%
% If you don't plan to use Computer Modern much or at all, it might
% (!)  be a good idea to make your own \texttt{fonttext.cfg}. Look at
% the comments below (docstrip module `text') to see what should
% should go into such a file.
%
% To change the math font setup use a copy of \texttt{fontmath.ltx}
% under the name \texttt{fontmath.cfg} and change this copy. However,
% dealing with this interface is even more a job for an expert than
% changing the text font setup --- in short, we don't encourage either.
```