# Latin Modern vs cm-super?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, latin-modern

I've read various answers to questions on here that suggest the original Computer Modern fonts have been superseded. Sometimes it is suggested we use the `cm-super` package, sometimes that we instead use latin modern fonts. Which is better? Which is easier to get working? (getting new fonts to work in LaTeX seems a daunting task...) Which look better?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Latin Modern is derived from cm, cm-super also.

- cm-super is a vectorization of cm bitmap fonts but mainly automatically done.
- The vectorization of Latin Modern is handmade.
- Latin Modern has revised metrics.
- Latin Modern provides more glyphs, especially diacritical characters. There are 72 text fonts, each of them containts more than 700 glyphs. In addition there are 20 math fonts. cm-super comes with more fonts but fewer glyphs, check its README file.
- Latin Modern development goes on.

**Update:** Now there's also a [Latin Modern Math font](http://www.gust.org.pl/gustnews/news-lm-math-en?set_language=en), available since July 2011.

Comment: I read that the vectorization was through MetaType1, which involves a METAPOST macro package, some \*nixy scripts, and changing the sources to *use* the macro package. Now, that does involve some manual labour, but surely "the vectorization is handmade" is a bit of a stretch? I mean, it's not like they hand-vectorized each glyph of each shape in each optical size -- they adapted the font code to (essentially) vectorize itself, and perhaps did some manual touch-ups afterwards, as I understand it.comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Will the LM Math fonts be included in the `lmodern` package or a separate package?

Comment: @You — if you look inside `lmodern.sty` you can see it includes code to set up the maths alphabets. Because they're a drop-in replacement for the default CM fonts, it doesn't take many lines of code.

Comment: Is there such thing as `Latin Modern` font to set? So far I found that this works `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Latin Modern Math}` but doesn't sound right to use a Math font for main font. Does it?

Answer (score 61):

In addition to what Stefan wrote:

- Both are easy to use in any modern TeX distribution. The distributor has taken care of this for you
- cm-super takes up more space in your distribution, but in my testing lmodern generally takes up more space in your generated PDF. This is because lmodern uses font subroutines, which all must be put in the PDF, even if you only use a subset of glyphs
- lmodern is available in the same optical sizes as computer modern, cm-super is available in more optical sizes (this 'feature' of cm-super switched is off by using the fix-cm package (highly recommended))
- With cm-super it's recommended to use the fix-cm package to fix a lot of broken design decisions in cm-super (and in addition this makes the final PDF a bit smaller)
- Neither cm-super or lmodern are as well-hinted (for onscreen reading) as the bluesky computer modern fonts. Hinting is simply too hard to get right and the lmodern developers don't focus on it. Both cm-super and lmodern each have their hinting flaws, and I'm not sure which I prefer
- As I understand it, neither cm-super or lmodern will give exactly identical page breaks as the traditional computer modern, but lmodern will be closer

Comment: what is this bluesky computer modern you mention?

Comment: The bluesky computer modern is the standard PostScript type 1 conversion of computer modern, that all(?) modern TeX distributions should use when producing PostScript or PDF output. They were professionally hinted by Y&Y under contract to Blue Sky, and originally sold commercially (free TeX distros used the inferior bakoma fonts) until the AMS bought the rights and released them to the TeX community. See http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/fonts/bluesky.html

Comment: I'm no expert, but I did a little digging - pdftex in TexLive 2010 will indeed use the "blue sky" version of `cmr` by default (located in `texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/`). However, upon choosing `[T1]{inputenc}`, the implementation defaults to `cm-super`.

Comment: @MattB the `cm` fonts don't exist in t1 encoding (see above), so latex is set up to switch to `cm-super` if you ask for t1 `cm`.  i use lm for any actual document i want to look knuthian, and largely ignore `cm`/`cm-super`, nowadays

Comment: What are these 'font subroutines'? Certainly LM subsets in PDF. To be honest, I don't understand what these even *could* be, if we're talking about type1 fonts. Really mystified. (I assume you're right, since nobody has said otherwise in 7 years, but that doesn't make me any less mystified.)

Comment: The [type 1 spec](https://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/T1_SPEC.PDF) tells about subroutines. This [latin modern paper](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb27-0/jackowski.pdf) describes how latin modern uses them.

Answer (score 50):

If you're saying "Meh, all these differences don't really seem to matter to me", here's something that might be relevant for you, especially if you're writing in German:

`cm-super`'s sharp s ⟨ß⟩ is ugly imho. Latin Modern replaced it with the original Computer Modern one, which is prettier. This is actually an easy way to tell the two apart – if there is a ⟨ß⟩ in the text you're looking at.

Edit: Following [Philippe's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super/65103#comment138677_65103) about accents, I added some to the picture. Note that this now is not a street name anymore that you're likely to find in Germany ...

[image: ß in cm-super vs. lmodern]
(both at 12pt, zoomed in)

Comment: Indeed; I think I remember reading that the cm-super ß glyph was controversial since it didn't follow the original CM design. It does seem like an odd choice because an innocent `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` line would give the obviously different output.

Comment: Do you have any idea why they changed it?

Comment: Another easy way to tell apart cm-super and lmodern is the accents. In cm-super, accents on `é` or `è` are badly positioned (they seem to be falling off the letter) and less slanted.

Comment: @doncherry — no idea, it was before my time, so to speak.

Comment: The ß of cm-super is more a ligature of long and short/round s: ſs → ß, while the ß of lmodern is more a ligature of long s and _curved_ z: ſʒ → ß.

Answer (score 31):

One more addition: cm-super contains Cyrillic fonts and lmodern doesn't.

Comment: As the word "Latin" in "Latin Modern" hints ;-)

Answer (score 10):

As Lev Bishop explained, both cm-super and lmodern have problems with hinting; the PDF files may look bad in some PDF viewers.

Therefore I'd suggest that you consider the third option as well: `\usepackage{ae}`. Looks good on screen and works everywhere without installing anything new.

Comment: you don't get eth and thorn (icelandic), or the various guillemets, but if `ae` covers your needs, it is a good choice. 

another possibility is the 'european computer modern' commercial fontset from micropress, inc. Price is about $150. Don't know what the quality of the hinting is like.

Comment: ae is not a good choice. If you use non-ascii characters copy & paste will be broken in the pdf. If you don't use such chars than you don't need T1 encoding and the ae fonts.

Comment: @Ulrike: Yes, copy & paste will be broken, but at least the PDF file *looks good*, both on screen and on paper.

Answer (score 7):

The Latin Modern fonts are terribly hinted (or maybe not hinted at all)? This is LMRoman12-regular on Windows 7:

[image: Awful hinting]

That ain't right.

I have managed to get a decent Computer Modern style font with hinting in a modern format! Here's how:

1. Download [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download).
2. Open the Latin Modern .otf fonts in [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/downloads/) (you must run FontForge as admin for some reason; obviously high quality code... /s).
3. Go to Element -> Font Info -> General and set the Em size to 1024.
4. File -> Generate Fonts
5. Format: TrueType
6. Uncheck "Validate Before Saving" (Latin Modern has some errors apparently).
7. Save the font.
8. Download Freetype's TTF autohinter: https://freetype.org/ttfautohint/doc/ttfautohint.html.
9. Autohint the TTF with it. I used all the default settings.
10. Behold!

Before:

[image: Awful hinting]

After:

[image: Nice hinting]

I am really impressed with the autohinting. I have not converted all the fonts yet, or checked out how to make bold/italic/slant/whatever work.

I put all the fonts converted by this procedure at http://concentriclivers.appspot.com/LatinModernTTFHinted.7z [broken link].

This is the best way to use latin modern in Microsoft Word.

Comment: So can you get this into the cm-super package? Or, is this not a good idea to always do?

Comment: Any chance to have the auto-hinting in LaTeX's lmodern package? Or is this less of a problem with LaTeX?

Comment: Yeah I never noticed this as a problem with LaTeX. No idea why.