# How do I make smaller pdf file sizes with pdflatex? (Or, how do I make pdflatex use CFF fonts?)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, file-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create small final pdf files for the internet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-final-pdf-files-for-the-internet)

When I compile

tex -> dvi -> ps -> pdf

I have a 9 MB file... something emailable

When I .tex -> pdf  with pdflatex, its 44 MB

I read that its likely largely due to how pdflatex embeds the Type 1 fonts..

Does anyone have any idea about how or what to adjust to get smaller filesizes with pdflatex?

Thanks

Comment: sorry..dup question as per comments

Comment: By the way, I find it somewhat unlikely that you have 35Mb of fonts in your document. pdfsizeopt with the --stats option can give some clue about where the space is being used (acrobat professional gives a slightly different set of statistics that may also be useful: Advanced -> PDF Optimizer -> Audit space usage...)

Comment: Are you using `microtype` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pdfsizeopt, as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-final-pdf-files-for-the-internet/2202#2202).