# Generate large document by pdfTeX, then break result into many PDF files while preserving links

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf, links

This is the PDF file of a book I wrote: http://www.abstractmath.org/Handbook/handbook.pdf

It takes a long time to download because it is a big file.  I generated it using pdfLaTeX.  Is there a way to generate it as many different PDF files while automatically preserving the links between pieces?  (It makes quite heavy use of internal links.)

Comment: I had a similar question and some useful answers are provided here:[Does Hyperref work between files][1]




  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files

Answer (score 5):

I'm also not sure if this is possible. (You'd think it should be, but PDF manipulation doesn't seem to be very friendly about internal linking.) An alternative is to generate the files separately and then link between the PDFs explicitly with the `xr` package.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit orthogonal to your question, but is probably useful: Your pdf can be compressed by around a factor of 3 even without splitting it up (using the techniques I wrote [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-final-pdf-files-for-the-internet/2202#2202)). [Here is the compressed version](http://drop.io/fspza3q).

To answer your actual question: acrobat professional can split a PDF into chunks (choosing the breaks in various ways: by file size, by number of pages, by top-level headings) but as far as I can tell, there is no way to keep intra-chunk links active (pdf hyperlinks outside of the pdf are always a bit awkward anyway, because the PDF needs to be aware of its own location in order for the links to work, which makes it rather non-portable).