# Link to local (PDF) file

Tags: hyperref, pdf, external-files, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does hyperref work between two files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files)

I want to make a link in LaTeX to a PDF file on my local network drive, i.e. when you click on it then Adobe Reader should open and show the file. What I tried is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{run:d:/my folder/test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41605

Answer (score 24):

Use `\href{run:d:/my folder/test.pdf}{<link text>}` instead of `\url{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:d:/my folder/test.pdf}{This is my link}
\end{document}
```

This works fine with Adobe Reader X (Windows).

Comment: Is it possible to go to a certain page, just like the internal links?

Comment: This syntax works at best not only with pdfs but also with other files extensions (e.g. Matlab figure files, etc.).

Comment: took me a while to make this work; finally noticed that a leading "/" on the file path seems to be not allowed.  That is, I was using something like `\href{run:/d:/...}` and that was not working.

Comment: According the [this reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#.5Chref), the leading "/" IS allowed.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Adobe Reader XI. The link is littered with %20, %22 etc that prevent the hyperlink from pointing to the right file

Comment: Is there any explanation on *why* that `run:` prefix is needed? In my tests without that prefix it works well in most readers. But the TexLive built-in PDF reader/preview e.g. does _not_ open the file if you prepend the path with `run:`. Without the prefix, it seems to work in many readers, too.

Comment: @Gqqnbig You can add #page=nn to the .pdf filename, and a browser should open it and go to that page nn.