# How do I reference supplementary files such as tables in Excel format?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, external-files

Some of the information I need to include in my thesis are extremely long tables that will only be provided in the digital copy as supplementary files, most likely in Excel's XLS format or similar.

Now, these supplementary tables obviously need to be named and referenced and I would like to use the LaTeX way, i.e., not writing:

```
...the full list is provided in Supplementary Table 2.4.
```

but rather:

```
...the full table is provided in Supplementary Table~\ref{tab:FullList}.
```

and then have the expected output.

I understand this is a not-so-common scenario, so I'm wondering if this is even possible. If yes, what's the right way to do it?

Comment: the http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/ package provides the makro `\href{target}{text}` that can link to external files as explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/link-to-local-pdf-file

Comment: Are there any news here? Did the comment above help you?

Comment: It is not a not-so-common scenario: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/118314/citing-supplementary-material-as-a-reference