# create a link to open another pdf, not in the current directory

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf

How can I make a hyperlink to a pdf file located somwhere out of the current directory of .tex file?

For example, my .tex file is located in C:\myWritings and the pdf file to be linked in the tex is located in C:\PDFs.

Comment: You can use `\href{<target file>}{<description>}` from `hyperref` but file will be opened in a browser.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert

```
\href{run:C:/PDFs/example.pdf}{This is descriptive link text}
```

, you have to use `\href` instead of `\url` according to [Link to local (PDF) file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/link-to-local-pdf-file)