# Link to local Matlab file

Tags: hyperref, external-files

I'm working on a document with hundreds of figures, that are generated from matlab. From time to time, I have to change among the hundreds of `.m` files to generate the corresponding matlab figure and therefore makes quite cumbersome the whole work.

I'm interested in a solution something [like](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/link-to-local-pdf-file) below, so that when I click any figure (or link) in generated `.pdf` (or in `.tex`) file the corresponding matlab `.m` file will open in Matlab.

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:d:/my folder/matlab.m}{This is my link}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would require a connection between the figure and the relevant matlab file, i.e. `Figure A` must 'know' that it has been generated with `matlabA.m` and `Figure B` is from `matlabB.m`

Comment: how to develop that connection?

Comment: You have to store some information of course or incorporate the file name of the matlab script somehow in the figure file name and retrieve ('parse') the file name for this

Comment: Perhaps something like `attachfile2` package provides is an alternative?