# Link to local html file

Tags: urls, href

I am trying to link to a local html file but nothing has worked.

I have tried:

1. `\href{file:path_to_file}{File}` or `\href{run:path_to_file}{File}`: does not open since preview/adobe does not recognize the html file as an html file and trying open to open with the preview/adobe. (this works for pdf but not html)
2. `\href{http:file:path_to_file}{File}`: preview/adobe opens the browser but the semicolon in the path is dropped, i.e., the browser is trying to open `filepath_to_file` and fails to locate the file

Using `\url{}` yields the same behaviors. Any idea?

Edit: also tried `\href{run:path_to_file}{File}` but did not work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to local (PDF) file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/link-to-local-pdf-file) // Use `run:` instead of `file:`

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Thanks! No `run:` does not work for html either. I should have mentioned this.

Comment: Can you please show the first error in your log file? And can you give us a short compilable TeX code resulting in this error?

Comment: @cccfran What exactly are you putting for `path_to_file`?