# undefined control sequence when cross-referencing with xr-hyper

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdftex, siunitx, external-files

I'm trying to create references between two documents.  Normally it works great, but I can't figure out why using `siunitx` inside a chapter name, causes build errors.

Simple example:

**doc1.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx,xr-hyper,hyperref,lipsum}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\externaldocument{doc2}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test \SI{1}{\GeV}}
\label{chap:test1}
\lipsum[1]
\ref{chap:test2}
\end{document}
```

**doc2.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx,xr-hyper,hyperref,lipsum}
\externaldocument{doc1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test \SI{2}{\GeV}}
\label{chap:test2}
\lipsum[1]
\ref{chap:test1}
\end{document}
```

**Build sequence**

```
$ pdflatex doc1.tex
...(no errors)
$ pdflatex doc2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Test \SI {1}{\GeV 
                             }\relax
```

I've narrowed it down to when `externaldocument` opens **doc1.aux**, it errors on the last line:`\newlabel{chap:test1}{{1}{1}{Test \SI {1}{\GeV }\relax }{chapter.1}{}}` properly.

Is there some way to make it parse the aux file properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Package `xr-hyper` expands the label contents. A better replacement for `xr-hyper` is `zref-xr` that also can import and export LaTeX labels:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx,hyperref,lipsum}

\usepackage{nameref,zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
\zexternaldocument*{doc1}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test \SI{2}{\GeV}}
\label{chap:test2}
\lipsum[1]
\ref{chap:test1}, \nameref{chap:test1}
\end{document}
```

Package `nameref` should be loaded before `\zexternaldocument`, because it changes the internal reference format. `hyperref` loads `nameref` later in `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 8):

add

```
 \let\GeV\relax
```

to each document before the call to `\externaldocument`

and it should run without error.

Answer (score 4):

[`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)'s `\GetTitleString` retrieves the sectional title and stores it in `\@currentlabelname`. You can override this *before* making the `\label` so that it doesn't include the macro contents from [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). The macro `\updatelabelname{<new name>}` below does this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\updatelabelname}[1]{% For correcting \@currentlabelname, if needed
  \xdef\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Include the above in both documents and use

#### `doc1.tex`

```
\chapter{Test \texorpdfstring{\SI{1}{\GeV}}{1 GeV}}
\updatelabelname{Test 1 GeV}
```

#### `doc2.tex`

```
\chapter{Test \texorpdfstring{\SI{2}{\GeV}}{2 GeV}}
\updatelabelname{Test 2 GeV}
```

Also note the use of `\texorpdfstring` to correctly switch between TeX-related (like ToC) and PDF content (like bookmarks), in general.