# How to make a link to a chapter in a local pdf file?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links

The title is self-explanatory.

Anything of that sort

```
\href{run:path/to/file.pdf#chapter2}{go to chapter 2 of file.pdf}
```

?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Does `hyperref` work between two files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41539/5764)

Comment: The usage of `\href` in such situation can be found in the package `macros2e`. In the [file `macros2e.tex`](http://www.scharrer-online.de/downloads/macros2e.tex) the macro `\exthref` creates links to the file `source2e.pdf`...