# How to cross-reference labels between two documents without hyperlinks, while still creating hyperlinks to labels within the same document?

Tags: hyperref, xr

I have two documents (A and B) with labels. I would like to reference the labels in document A from document B. I would like to use the `hyperref` package to create hyperlinks in document B to the labels within document B. I want to resolve the references in document B to document A with the correct numbering, but I do not want to create hyperlinks for theses references. Is this possible? My motivation is that document A is being published on an external site, so I can't link to references within it and I don't want broken hyperlinks.

- If I use the `xr-hyper` package (a great minimal example is available in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41547/25127) to the question "Does hyperref work between two files?"), LaTeX will create a link to document A from document B when document B references a label in document A.
- If I use the `xr` package instead of `xr-hyper`, LaTeX will create a hyper link to label 1 of document B when document B references label 1 of document A (i.e. it still tries to create hyperlinks but it does not link them outside of the document).

For a full minimal working example, look at this adapted version of the example given in [the answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41547/25127):

> `docA.tex`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\externaldocument[B-]{docB}[docB.pdf]% <- full or relative path 
\begin{document}
    This is a test for math.
    \begin{equation}
        E=mc^2 \label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    This is a second test for math.
    \begin{equation}
        r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \label{eq:2}
    \end{equation}
    In document B Eq.~~(\ref{B-eq:x}) 
\end{document}
```

> `docB.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{docA}[docA.pdf]% <- full or relative path
\begin{document}
  \setcounter{equation}{5}

  As was shown in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:1}) is it
  ... or in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:2}) is ...
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}-1=0 \label{eq:x}
  \end{equation}

  Here is a hyperlinked internal reference to \ref{eq:x}.
\end{document}
```

I want to produce a pdf with the first `\ref` in document B turned into a "1" but not hyperlinked to an external document and the last `\ref` in document B turned into a "6" and hyperlinked to `eq:x`.

Comment: Did you look at the `xr-hyper` package?

Comment: Can't you simply use `\ref*{...}` for the external references?

Comment: I have looked at xr-hyper a little bit, but I thought that was more for getting the links to actually point somewhere in the other document.  I will look more closely at it for an option to turn off hyperlinks to the external document.

Comment: Yes, good catch. I had overlooked the `\setcounter` statement. (Before finding that other question to reference, I had actually worked out basically the same minimal working example myself. Then when I found that question, I switched to its version, but I guess I didn't try compiling it to compare).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting an example with compilable code. As @UlrikeFischer has pointed out in an earlier comment, if the `hyperref` package is loaded, you should use `\ref*` instead of `\ref` to create a cross-reference that's not also a hypertarget. Please note that this applies *regardless* of whether the cross-reference's target is located in the same document or in some other document.

Still assuming that `hyperref` is loaded, one should use `\autoref*` rather than `\autoref` to create cross-references that (a) automatically provide the *name* of the item being cross-referenced (e.g., "section", "figure", "footnote", etc) as part of the call-out and (b) aren't hypertargets. Likewise, if the `cleveref` package is loaded in addition to the `hyperref` package, one should use `\cref*` and `\Cref*` instead of `\cref` and `\Cref` to create "clever" cross-references that aren't also hypertargets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So what if I wanted to be able to turn on and off the external hyperlinks quickly? Would the best option be to use a text editor that can find all `\ref{A-` instances and replace them with `\ref*{A-`, and vice versa? I suppose as long as I used a unique prefix like `A-` to distinguish the external labels from the internal ones that this method would work. I didn't know about `\ref*` when I asked the question, but I had been expecting there would be some option I could set in the preamble rather than changing the reference syntax.

Comment: @ws_e_c421 - Your idea of doing a global search-and-replace in DocB for instances of `\ref{A-` and replacing the instances with `\ref*{A-` would seem to be the right way to proceed. To turn hyperlinking back on, replacing all instances of `\ref*` with `\ref` should be rather easy to accomplish, right? I suspect that messing with, emmm, modifying the definition of `\ref` purely to "automate" the non-generation of hyperlinks seems like an open invitation to disaster.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is:

1. to patch the `xr-hyper` package so that it records all labels that it read from external documents; this allows us to distinguish between internal references that should be automatically hyperlinked and external references that should not.
2. to redefine the unstarred version of `hyperref`'s `\ref` to check whether the reference is external or not, and to essentially assume that the starred version was used if so.

I believe the following does what you want, changes only necessary to `docB.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% following code is to meet objectives of [How to cross-reference labels between two documents without hyperlinks, while still creating hyperlinks to labels within the same document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112603/how-to-cross-reference-labels-between-two-documents-without-hyperlinks-while-st)
% insert this after loading xr-hyper and hyperref but before calling \externaldocument
\makeatletter
% patch XR so that it records whether or not the label has come from an external file
\long\def\XR@test#1#2#3#4\XR@{%
  \ifx#1\newlabel
     \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname r@\XR@prefix#2\endcsname
       {\XR@addURL{#3}}%
     \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname isxr@r@\XR@prefix#2\endcsname{1}%
  \else\ifx#1\@input
     \edef\XR@list{\XR@list\filename@area#2\relax}%
  \fi\fi
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XR@aux
  \else\expandafter\XR@read\fi}

% every time \ref is used without an explicit star, check if it is an external reference or not
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\orig@T@ref\T@ref
    %patched \T@ref checks if the ref is from xr, and redirects to \@refstar if so
    % else it passes to \orig@T@ref
    \def\T@ref#1{%
        \ifcsname isxr@r@#1\endcsname
            %\typeout{sending #1 to refstar}%
            \@refstar{#1}%
        \else
            %\typeout{sending #1 to orig@T@ref}%
            \orig@T@ref{#1}%
        \fi
    }%
}%
\makeatother
% end patch

\externaldocument[A-]{docA}[docA.pdf]% <- full or relative path
\begin{document}
  \setcounter{equation}{5}

  As was shown in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:1}) is it
  ... or in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:2}) is ...
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}-1=0 \label{eq:x}
  \end{equation}

  Here is a hyperlinked internal reference to \ref{eq:x}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: docB output]

Note that this may not play well with other packages that hook into `\ref` etc.