# Using xr-hyper and hyperref - error when setting the page counter

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, xr

I am trying to set the page counter of `docB.tex` based on the page of `docA.tex` that contains the label `my-label`. I'm using the packages `xr-hyper` and `hyperref` based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files) example.

#### docA.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
    Here is a label. \label{my-label}
    It appears on page \pageref{my-label}.
\end{document}
```

#### docB.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{docA}
\begin{document}
    In docA, the label appears on page \pageref{A-my-label}.
    Set the page number to that: 
    \setcounter{page}{\pageref{A-my-label}}
\end{document}
```

I compile `docA.tex` twice for good luck, and it correctly produces a PDF that says

```
Here is a label. It appears on page 1.
```

However, when I compile `docB.tex` I get the error

```
./docB.tex:8: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.8 ...    \setcounter{page}{\pageref{A-my-label}}
```

I know the cross-referencing works correctly because if I comment out the `\setcounter` line, then line 6 correctly prints the page number. So the error comes from within the `\setcounter` call.

What am I missing?

Comment: `\pageref` can not be  used to set a counter even on a later pass, as it can have formatting commands or be in roman or whatever, and is made robust with an internal `\protect` that you see in the error message. You can use the zref packages to give a version of page ref that can be used in that way and defaults to 0 so it is always a legal number.

Comment: `\mbox{1}` would also print as 1 but not work in `\setcounter{page}{\mbox{1}}` for similar reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic line is:

```
\setcounter{page}{\pageref{A-my-label}}
```

Package `hyperref` adds a link and a link is not a number that can be used with `\setcounter`. Package `refcount` helps to extract the number from the reference:

```
\setcounterpageref{page}{A-my-label}
```

If the label is not yet defined, the default value `0` is used. The default can be changed by macro `\setrefcountdefault`. Example:

```
\begingroup % keep default change local
  \setrefcountdefault{1}%
  \setcounterpageref{page}{A-my-label}% global assignment
\endgroup
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, I added `\usepackage{refcount}` above `\usepackage{xr-hyper}` in both files and replaced the `\setcounter` line with the `\setcounterpageref` line you provided.