# Cross-Referencing (Number and Title/Name) between Different/Multiple Documents

Tags: cross-referencing, multiple-files

I have a large document (book, article or report) for which I want to produce a `beamer` presentation with some explanation: e. g. how the large document is structured and which chapter should be read by which audience.

In the `beamer` presentation I want to refer to some chapters, sections and so on. I want to refer using the **number** (e. g. *Chapter 1.2*) **AND** the the actual **title** / **name** (like with the [`nameref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref) package, e. g. *Introduction*).

I have seen that there are some older questions about this subject, e. g. this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539) (*Does hyperref work between two files?*).

> Are there new approaches apart from the [`xr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) package?

Comment: With `xr-hyper`, `\nameref` with an external label works (apart from a warning from `pdftex`).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Is your issue settled then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for asking. I am still working on a beamer theme :). Haven't tried it yet - I just assumed that it will work according to egreg's answer.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: @Bobyandbob No. The problem is not the first on my priority list, rather a nice to have for the future. I am sure that egreg's comment solves my question since he is very good at LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using egreg's comment:

> With `xr-hyper`, `\nameref` with an external label works (apart from a
> warning from pdftex).