# Launch a program from a pdf file created with LaTeX

Tags: external-files, links, program

I have found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files/41605#41605), but it regards opening a `.pdf` file from another one. I would like to open a `.ods` file from a link in the `.pdf` file, meaning it should launch LibreOffice Calc.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, Texlive 2020 and TeXstudio 3.0.4.

I tried `\href{run:/home/andrea/Downloads/Aufgabe-kaese.ods}{Tabelle}`, but it doesn't work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: `\href{run:tabelle.ods}{Tabelle}` works fine for me in adobe reader (on windows), but sumatra doesn't launch anything.

Comment: You could try adding the file to the pdf directly with packages like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2 or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile, such an approach may have better viewer support than launching an external program through `\href`.

Comment: @Marijn `attachfile2` doesn't work. I will try with `embedfile` and will report.

Comment: @Andyc what exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"? Do you get an error when you compile? Or is the file link not present in the pdf? Or is it not clickable? Or does it not open the file? Or does it not open the file in LibreOffice? Which pdf viewer do you use? Is it just for you or do you want it to work if you send the pdf to other people as well?

Comment: @Marijn The source compiles without errors. The link is there. When you click on it, it opens an empty annotation window, where you can type something, but nothing of the content of the table shows up. It doesn't open LibreOffice. I use the viewer that comes with Ubuntu (Document Viewer). I sure would like it to work for anybody, but if it were working for me, it would be a good step forward.