# How to make the PDFs produced by pdfLaTeX smaller?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, file-size

I feel that the PDFs produced by `pdflatex` are too huge. So for example my 50 page book with no illustrations is 500KB. I feel it should be more like 50K or even less. The `.tex` files together are just 40KB. Anyone knows why the final PDF is so huge and is there a way to compress it to make smaller?

Comment: See also [How to create small final PDF files for the Internet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-final-pdf-files-for-the-internet).

Comment: It might be useful to know which TeX system you use. There is more compression in modern TeX Live systems, by for example compressing how hyperlinks are constructed.

Comment: It's normally mostly the fonts. Also hyperlinks can add to the size if you have many of them. My 10page package manuals jumped from 120k to 460k just for changing the font and the font encoding.

Comment: Does the size difference actually matter? The price of 1MB of hard drive storage is somewhere around 0.001 to 0.01 cent (0.1 for SSD). Bandwidth is probably something like 0.00001 (Amazon S3) to 1 cent (AT&T mobile) per MB. (These measurements are of course completely unscientific.) I'd rather have nice fonts and diagrams.

Comment: @Peteris: From that, I'd guess you have the latest TeX Live, which makes use of hyperlink compression in the PDF. As @Martin says, most of the size here is probably font-related.

Comment: If you have Acrobat, you can determine how the space is being used by going to `Advanced > PDF Optimizer > Audit space usage`

Comment: Check the PDF version that you are producing (using, for example, the `pdfinfo` tool). If the PDF version is < 1.5, upgrade your TeX system.

Comment: While the methods given by Daniel, Evan, and Keks on this thread may or may not work effectively, I think that there is something that is not addressed in their answers. Which is, how to avoid a latex build from blowing up in the first place? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 182):

A common approach is to let [Ghostscript](https://ghostscript.com/index.html) (`gs`) optimize and compress the PDF after it has been created with `pdflatex`.

Ghostscript is installed by most Linux distributions and is easily available for other platforms (Windows as [binaries](https://ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html), MacOS via MacPorts). In fact, almost all size-optimizing tools for PDF (save for Acrobat) you can find on the internet, internally use Ghostscript -- so you can as well call it directly.

There is a plethora of options available; I personally use the following:

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```

I use this mostly for beamer presentations, where it gets me a size reduction of 60–70 percent. (A 10 MiB lecture note becomes 3–4 MiB in size.)

**Edit 2020-02-06:** Added `-dPrinted=false` to preserve Hyperlinks.
**Edit 2020-09-10:** Changed `-dCompatibilityLevel` from 1.4 to 1.5 as `pdflatex` outputs PDF 1.5 by default since 2010.

Comment: I wonder if you get the same size reduction if you use  `\pdfminorversion=5 \pdfcompresslevel=9 \pdfobjcompresslevel=3`, i.e. maximum compression with PDF v1.5.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Not really, with my lecture these options give only a size reduction of 110 Bytes
9825306 no-compression.pdf
9825196 pdflatex-compression.pdf
4318774 gs-compression.pdf
4318772 pdflatex-gs-compression.pdf

Comment: The numbers before the filename are the actual size. (It kind of bugs me that all newlines get lost when saving a comment...)

Comment: @Daniel: That's probably because you use similar settings by default, i.e. the "no-compression.pdf" is actually already compressed. Set `\pdfcompresslevel=0` to see the difference.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I get interesting results:  By setting `\pdfcompresslevel=0 \pdfobjectcompresslevel=0` the resulting file size gets *smaller* (even though only a bit: 9630339 instead of 9825196). Piping this result through `gs` gives exactly the same size as piping no-compression.pdf through it:4318772. So the bottom line is that (at least for beamer presentations) `gs` reduces the size quite a bit, independently from the choosen pdflatex compression options.

Comment: @Daniel: That's weird. I guess it depends quite a bit on the document.

Comment: @Daniel: Pdf files with  JPEG2000 image compression cannot be viewed on iPad. Will the same issue happen when the pdf files are compressed by gs?

Comment: @Daniel: can we call `gs` indirectly using `ps2pdf` with the same switches above?

Comment: @xport: I don't really know, but I guess so.

Comment: `pdfsizeopt` uses this kind of compression through `gs` as one of the tricks it uses to get smaller PDFs (it also uses a whole tonne of other tricks, so it will generally do better than `gs` alone). See also [this whitepaper](http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/downloads/detail?name=pts_pdfsizeopt2009.psom.pdf) on a whole series of techniques for getting smaller PDFs.

Comment: If I use `pdf2ps -> ps2pdf`, `pdffonts` shows no fonts as embedded. Is the size optimisation at the cost of portability?

Comment: @cfr: Are the fonts embedded in the original PDF?

Comment: @Daniel Yes and `pdffonts` confirms this.

Comment: Not every PDF feature will survive such `gs` post-treatment, OCGs (PDF Layers) for instance.

Comment: This works for me on Windows: gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -o small_printer.pdf original.pdf

Comment: I am a beginner, I have tried to enter the line `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=my_file_name-compressed.pdf my_file_name.pdf` in my TexStudio Terminal, but it gives an error `'gs' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file`? What should I try from here? thanks

Comment: @Lello: The `gs` executable has to be in the search path for executables. I don't know TexStudio enough, though, to tell you if there is a dedicated setting for it or if it just uses the PATH from the environment.

Comment: @Daniel thank you, in the end I have compressed my PDF by using only figures in the PDF format (rather than png or jpg)

Comment: Worth mentioning the `-dPrinted=false` option which preservers your hyperlinks in the document and adds almost nothing to the compressed size.

Comment: @joaoal: Thanks a lot! I stumbled over exactly this problem a couple of days ago. Actually, I was quite surprised that links do not work: Either I had never tried that before or this option used to be the default in previous versions of `gs`. Anyway, I will add this to the answer.

Comment: I tried this with a LaTeX doc on windows, works fine. However, I have rotated pages in the LaTex doc and gs outputs this to landscape format. How can I change this?

Comment: @Daniel Can you clarify in your answer on whether this is a lossless compression? `pdfsizeopt`, which does lossless compression is a product of detailed engineering effort, but does a worse job (slower to run and bigger file size) than your ghostscript-based answer!  If your `gs` solution is truly lossless, then this is a clear winner!

Comment: @Daniel ping. can you please have a look at my question above?

Comment: @DrKrishnakumarGopalakrishnan: Sorry, but I don't really know. I assume it is lossy to some extend (regarding output resolution), but I never really noticed any substantial difference.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the "Open Contents" feature when going through `gs` ? I saw that it was not yet supported, but the message where I saw it was from several years... Also, how does `gs` to achieve such space reduction, I am kind of baffled by this and I would like to know what is "lost" in the compression.

Comment: I get `**** Error 'gs' ignored -- ExtGState missing from Resources. Output may be incorrect.` It still seems to work though. Any idea what that means?

Comment: This command just compressed my `pdflatex`-generated letter by 20x 

Answer (score 21):

Here is a revised version of the script above.  The basics are unchanged, but it now handles paths and such in a sane manner, automatically copies the new over the old IFF the new file is smaller then the original (and not 0).  It also gives some info on space savings.  For some unknown reason, running it again can give even smaller output, but usually not by much.  The first run gives the big speedup.

For example:

```
ekl@Taro:~/Documents⟫ optpdf techResume.pdf 
Saving 1245351 bytes (now 6% of old)
ekl@Taro:~/Documents⟫ optpdf techResume.pdf 
Saving 31 bytes (now 99% of old)
ekl@Taro:~/Documents⟫ optpdf techResume.pdf 
Saving 7 bytes (now 99% of old)
ekl@Taro:~/Documents⟫ optpdf techResume.pdf 
Didn't make it smaller! Keeping original
```

It is legal to give it long paths, <s>but it currently doesn't like spaces in your filenames.  Sorry.  Getting shell scripts to handle this correctly in all instances is a pain, so just don't don't do it.</s>

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# optpdf file.pdf
#   This script will attempt to optimize the given pdf

file="$1"
filebase="$(basename "$file" .pdf)"
optfile="/tmp/$$-${filebase}_opt.pdf"
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
        -sOutputFile="${optfile}" "${file}"

if [ $? == '0' ]; then
    optsize=$(stat -c "%s" "${optfile}")
    orgsize=$(stat -c "%s" "${file}")
    if [ "${optsize}" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No output!  Keeping original"
        rm -f "${optfile}"
        exit;
    fi
    if [ ${optsize} -ge ${orgsize} ]; then
        echo "Didn't make it smaller! Keeping original"
        rm -f "${optfile}"
        exit;
    fi
    bytesSaved=$(expr $orgsize - $optsize)
    percent=$(expr $optsize '*' 100 / $orgsize)
    echo Saving $bytesSaved bytes \(now ${percent}% of old\)
    rm "${file}"
    mv "${optfile}" "${file}"
fi
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice that you output actual numbers. For a text only document of about 40 pages (created by ConTeXt), I get a reduction of only 2% in size; but for a 50 page presentation (again created by ConTeXt with lots of images and colors), I get a 40% reduction in size.

Comment: I'm not sure why running it again will reduce it in size more.  Its a ghostscript issue.  But, its usually the first run that does the big lifting.  Its safe to run it over and over - I even considered doing a loop to run it until it won't reduce any more.

Comment: If you get errors like `stat: illegal option -- c` and `line 14: [: : integer expression expected`, you must change `stat -c "%s"` into `stat -f "%z"` in lines 12 and 13.

Comment: Thanks for that! It shrinked my 50 pages pdflatex document with images to 37% of original size - pdfsizeopt produced a 86% sized file.

Comment: I tried your code but I get the error: GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Device 'pdfwrite' requires an output file but no file was specified.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
: No such file or directoryFile=/tmp/1244-foo.pdf
./optpdf: line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Are you sure you cut/pasted the code correctly?

Comment: I edited the code so that it works even with files that have spaces in their name. (Basically just adding quotes at appropriate places). I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: No problem.  I always forget about that sort of thing since I hate spaces in filenames.  I generally use a CLI and hate having to deal with escaping spaces!

Comment: @EvanLanglois *Suggestion*: put your very useful script altogether with a permissive license (GPLv2, BSD, MIT or so) on github.

Comment: @EvanLanglois Can you clarify in your answer on whether this is a lossless compression? `pdfsizeopt`, which does lossless compression is a product of detailed engineering effort, but does a worse job (slower to run and bigger file size) than your ghostscript-based answer!  If your `gs` solution is truly lossless, then this is a clear winner!

Comment: @orzechow Yes. I just had the same experience. For all its clever engineering`pdfsizeopt` is slower and produces slightly bigger pdfs  than this `gs` based solution for me. `pdfsizeopt` is truly a lossless solution though. We just need some clarity on whether ` gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -sOutputFile` is also lossless. If so, clearly `gs` is the clear winner!

Comment: @Krishna  It's just running it through ghostscript.  I've never heard of a lossy compression in ghostscript or any lossy techniques to compress a PDF or PS in a lossy manner.  Lossy compression techniques just don't apply here.

Comment: @EvanLanglois Apologies. But I found your sentence a bit confusing. Lossless is better than lossy right? Is ghostscript lossless?

Comment: @DrKrishnakumarGopalakrishnan Sorry I never saw this.  I've been digging into PDF options and there are some options to compress images, but when images are already compressed, they pass through unaltered.  There are options to detect duplicate images and subset fonts and even downsize images to optimize for specific output devices.  Further tweaking can give a few percent better compression, especially if the input images are huge.

Answer (score 17):

There is a wonderful script to shrink a PDF: https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt . I've been using it for years and can recommend it. The main effect is that it compresses the embedded fonts. Very helpfull if a font is large, like Linux Libertine. The script shrinks such a PDF (if no pictures are included) to 10% of the size!

Using it under Windows requires carefull installation to get all the necessary *.dll files.

Once in a while the script quits with an error message. The most frequent reason is that Multivalent has an issue. Simply avoid multivalent with the command `pdfsizeopt.py --use-multivalent=false ...` .

Another issue comes up, if you include other PDFs made by pdftex. Sometimes -- especially with Linux Libertine -- the italic letters in the included PDFs get garbled. We can avoid this by adding as first line to the *.tex file: `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`.

Comment: @ Keks Dose. I have a pdf file (18MB) generated by Texify->dvi-pdf, including many .eps figs. I tried to use `pdfsizeopt` you recommended to reduce its volume to be less than 3MB. With the commandline: c:\ pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt --use-multivalent=false --do-unify-fonts=false c:\pdfs\manuscript.pdf. It turns out that it only reduces the input-pdf by 1% or so. Can you give me some further advice?

Comment: @lxy Many ways. Obviously: reduce the size of the pics before including them, without that, you won't get far. Use multivalent, instead of `=false`. If available, use Adobe Pro to shrink the size.

Comment: @ Keks Dose. Thanks! However with `--use-multivalent=true`, cmd gives me error `Multivalent.jar not found`...

Comment: @lyx Well, you'll probably have to install it. The correct way depends on your OS. There used to be a manual by the author of pdfsizeopt.

Comment: I was able to follow the directions perfectly. Problem I had is that my input file was 28 MB, and my output was 27 MB. There appears to way to tailor the output size.