# Which one produces a pdf with the smaller file size? pdflatex or latex-dvips-ps2pdf?

Tags: pdftex, ps2pdf, dvips

Assume I have a screenshot in png format and make a copy of it in eps format by using ImageMagick.

I create two input file, namely `ForPNG.tex` and `ForEPS.tex`. `ForPNG.tex` imports the png image and is compiled by pdflatex. `ForEPS.tex` imports the eps image and is compiled by latex-dvips-ps2pdf.

The question is, which one produces the smaller pdf file in size?

In my experience, `ForEPS.pdf` will be smaller than `ForPNG.pdf`. But I am not sure whether it is a summary.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question, so I post it as a comment: Actually, both approaches are not particularly good in producing small PDF files. If you aim at a small PDF, I suggest to compress the resulting PDF afterwards (e.g., using `gs` as suggested in [How to make the PDFs produced by pdflatex smaller](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller/19047#19047)). I am pretty sure that any significant difference between both routes basically disappears after `gs`-compression.

Comment: Another route: Use something other than .png. It's a screen capture, so do you really need every bit preserved? Convert the .png file to a .jpg file using some graphics converter program. It's fairly easy to reduce the size of a typical screen shot by 2/3 or even more without too much loss of quality.

Comment: There is a python-script called pdfsizeopt.py, http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/ which reduces the size of pdfs. I use it frequently, but with texlive 2010 you need to begin your *.tex-file with `\pdfminorversion4`

Comment: @xport: Should I turn it into a real answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite my comment to the original question, I have now come to the conclusion that the `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` route produces smaller PDF files than `pdflatex` *alone*.

However, in my answer to [How to make the PDFS produced by pdflatex smaller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller/19047#19047) I suggested to use `gs` to compress the resulting PDF, which gets you a significant reduction in size. As `ps2pdf` is as well built on `gs` internally, one can also directly pass compression options to `ps2pdf`, so in the end it should not matter.

I made some quick experiments with a beamer presentation. In these experiments the `pdflatex-gs` route lead to only 1 percent smaller PDFs than `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

So the bottom line is: **With respect to the goal of small PDF files, it doesn't matter.**

You can just choose your frontend depending on other constraints (e.g., `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` if you use `pstricks` or `pdflatex-gs` to support transparencies in `pgf/tikz` images).

Comment: PDF produced by `latex->dvips->ps2pdf->gs` is smaller than one produced by `pdflatex->gs`.

Answer (score 2):

[This whitepaper](http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/downloads/detail?name=pts_pdfsizeopt2009.psom.pdf) contains extensive discussion about the pros and cons of different ways of generating small PDFs from TeX, including pdftex, or tex-dvips-ps2pdf, or dvipdfm, or dvipdfmx. With and without subsequent size optimization using several tools (alone and in combination): ps2psdf, pdf enhancer, acrobat pro, pdfsizeopt, multivalent. Each of those tools have a bunch of different settings. With various tricks in the TeX source (image optimization, etc). They investigate various different types of document (image-heavy, text-heavy, etc).

The final recommended workflow for small PDFs is: 1. use pdftex; 2. process with pdf enhancer or acrobat pro if you have them; 3. process with pdfsizeopt (including the optional multivalent step).