# Why does pdflatex produce bigger output files than latex+dvipdfm?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, file-size, dvi-mode, dvipdfmx

Consider this sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

When I compile this with `latex` and then use `dvipdfm`, the output file is 7893 bytes. When I use `pdflatex`, the output PDF is a whopping 20696 bytes. Naturally, the outputs are visually indistinguishable one from another.

Why does this happen? What does `pdflatex` put in there that takes so much space?

For reference, I have used the latest MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7, and ran the commands without any extra switches.

Comment: pdflatex generates "verbose" PDFs; the results are probably similar if you (lossless) compress the PDF afterwards as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18987/3751.

Comment: @Daniel: Yeah, when I ran `ghostscript` on the PDF from `pdflatex`, I got pretty much the same size as the other one. Still, that doesn't answer the *why* part of the question.

Comment: Could it be because `dvipdfm` processes an *already processed* version of a file (`.dvi`), while `pdflatex` processes a file from scratch (`.tex`). As such, there could be additional (unused) information contained within when processing it with the latter, while the former could selectively include only "the necessary components."

Comment: pdflatex embeds the font in type 1 format and dvipdfmx embeds the font in type 1c format. I think the latter compresses better, but I cannot find a reference to back the claim up. Use `pdffonts <pdf-file>` to see the difference in embedded fonttypes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Martin Heller has stated the correct answer: `dvipdfm` uses a different font format than `pdftex`. You can look into the PDF file by loading it into a text editor. Sometimes (well, often), the objects are compressed and you only see some data. So you either need a decompression algorithm built into your head, or use a tool like [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) to uncompress the objects (that is what I do):

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable test-pdflatex.pdf test-pdflatex-long.pdf
```

Now the output file is much more readable and you can now compare the output of `dvipdfm` and `pdftex`. I don't know if this applies to all cases, but in this example you can take a look at the font object:

```
% dvipdfm:
9 0 obj
<<
  /FontFile3 11 0 R
  /Ascent 694
  /CapHeight 683
  /Descent -194
  /Flags 6
  /FontBBox [-40 -250 1009 750 ]
  /FontName /DJLCQW+CMR10
  /ItalicAngle 0
  /StemV 69
  /Type /FontDescriptor
>>
endobj
```

and

```
% pfdtex
9 0 obj
<<
  /FontFile 11 0 R
  /Ascent 694
  /CapHeight 683
  /CharSet (/A/C/D/E/I/L/M/N/P/Q/S/U/V/a/b/c/comma/d/e/f/g/h/hyphen/i/j/l/m/n/o/one/p/period/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/y)
  /Descent -194
  /Flags 4
  /FontBBox [ -40 -250 1009 750 ]
  /FontName /QJZLYL+CMR10
  /ItalicAngle 0
  /StemV 69
  /Type /FontDescriptor
  /XHeight 431
>>
endobj
```

Both have different entries referring to the font file (`/FontFile3` and `/FontFile`). According to the table 126 "Embedded font organization for various font types" in the [PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=297), the entry `/FontFile` refers to a Type1 font program and `/FontFile3` to whatever the subtype in the referred stream is. So we need to take a look at object #11 in the `dvipdfm` file:

```
11 0 obj
<<
  /Subtype /Type1C
  /Length 12 0 R
>>
stream
....
endstream
endobj
```

So it is `Type1C`, which is according to the same table in the PDF spec: "Type 1–equivalent font program represented in the Compact Font Format (CFF), as described in [Adobe Technical Note #5176](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/font/pdfs/5176.CFF.pdf), The Compact Font Format Specification."

To find out what the secret of CFF is, a look at the introduction of "The Compact Font Format Specification" suffices:

> Principal space savings are a result of using a compact binary representation for most of the information, sharing of common data between fonts, and defaulting frequently occurring data.