# Get a smaller pdf file out of pdflatex

Tags: pdf, pdftex, file-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the PDFs produced by `pdflatex` smaller?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller)

I'm using the [`moderncv` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) to create my CV.

Now I was wondering if there is a way to get a smaller output, because the generated file (even without the picture) is still > 300kb.

Is there anything I can do to generate a smaller PDF keeping the same quality of the output (or very similar)?

Comment: Did you added a picture of yours? What size is it?

Comment: The picture now is 20k or so, even removing it completely it's still too big.

Comment: Did you tried building it with the same tool as the example files (xdvipdfm)? What did you tried so far?

Comment: That command wants a dvi as input as far as I understand, and I think that I have to produce a Pdf using moderncv.. I was thinking about something like decreasing output quality, removing embedded fonts or something, is it possible?