# big pdf size due to many small colored boxes

Tags: pdf, performance

*additional info at bottom*

I was going to use `\colorbox`es in verbatim mode, one per letter, but this increased significantly the size of pdf (produced via `latex+dvipdfmx` but `pdflatex` is similar, and I did further testing with it).

Drawing a yellow rule appears simpler than drawing a letter glyph, but from naïve testing, the PDF is more economical when it has to do many letters than when it has to do many small rules. Is there a way to tell `pdflatex` that something will be used over and over again, to store it somewhere, and economically use a pointer to it when it is needed? A bit I guess like what is automatically done for the glyphs picked up from the partially embedded font.

In the sort of `MWE` below, I see that the pdf file size is not outrageous when I have thousands of copies of the same type of colored box, about 4 bytes to switch to yellow, draw a rectangle, switch back to normal color, is not bad. But it is still quite more than what it takes to code the drawing of a letter `X` for example. Is there a way to obtain more compact PDF ?

(I tried `ps2pdf` which is ok here, but fails in my real life case to reduce the file size as obtained from dvipdfmx; in fact the file size goes from 1.1M to 1.5M).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

Hello.

% 28367 bytes for 4000 boxes
% 19844 bytes for 2000 boxes
% 15558 bytes for 1000 boxes
% 11658 bytes for 100 boxes
% 11167 bytes for 1 box
% about 4.4 bytes per colored box.
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{\colorbox{yellow}{\phantom{X}}}

\count255 4000
\noindent\loop
\usebox{\mybox}
%\colorbox{yellow}{\phantom{X}}
\advance\count255 by -1
\ifnum\count255>0
\repeat

% 11695 bytes for 1000 X
% 12272 bytes for 2000 X
% 12895 bytes for 3000 X
% 13057 bytes for 4000 X
% 13603 bytes for 5000 X
% \sbox{\mybox}{X}
% \count255 5000
% \noindent\loop
% \usebox{\mybox}
% \advance\count255 by -1
% \ifnum\count255>0
% \repeat

\end{document}
```

---

I report here on my testing with `pdfxform` which I was doing just a the time [wipet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205459/4686) appeared. I used the following test file. This is now on an old TL2010. With otherwise default settings the PDF is a PDF 1.5 file. I got `26907` bytes with the word `Hello` and `4000` yellow boxes done with `\usebox` and `23972` bytes using the `\pdfxform` way.

Then in my real use case, again on `TL2010` (and `dvipdfmx` has evolved since) I get the following order of magnitudes:

1. for a source not doing any boxes but only letters (in monotype), the `dvipdfmx` produced file has about `580000` bytes and the `pdflatex` one has about `760000` bytes (font used in the body of the document is mainly `newtxtt` which I have added to my `TL2010`).
2. when I do all the colored boxes, the `dvipdfmx` now weighs about `930000` bytes (but at home it was about `1050000` bytes) and the `pdflatex` one `1122000` bytes.
3. If I now do the `\pdfxform` thing I get a file of `1090000` bytes.

Conclusion: there is indeniably some gain, but `pdflatex+\pdfxform` still produces a bigger file in my case than `dvipdfmx`. And when I don't use at all the colored boxes, my `dvipdfmx` file is about `40%` smaller...

The increase of file size via adding the boxes is about `350k` (for both compilation routes) and using `\pdfxform` saves me about `30k`, which is nice but still frustrating.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\fboxsep0pt

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{\colorbox{yellow}{\strut\phantom{X}}}

% USE OF A BOX
% gives pdf file of 26907 bytes
% This is a 1.5 PDF file pdfTeX-1.40.11  (TL2010)
\count255 4000
\noindent\loop
\penalty0
\usebox{\mybox}%
\advance\count255 by -1
\ifnum\count255>0
\repeat

% % USE OF \pdfxform
% % gives pdf file of 23972 bytes
% \pdfxform\mybox % attention, empties box register

% \count255 4000
% \noindent\loop
% \penalty0
% \hbox{\pdfrefxform \pdflastxform}%
% \advance\count255 by -1
% \ifnum\count255>0
% \repeat

\end{document}
```

One last bit of info: in my real use case, the document has currently about `150` pages, and there are between 5 and 10 uses of words per page with their letters having a yellow background, actually I can count them: `32297` boxes! Thus the penalty if of about `10` bytes for each such yellow rectangle, and using `\pdfxform` doesn't improve it that much.

I have redone my tests on my real use case of a `152` pages document with `32297` boxes. To make it cleaner, I have removed the verbatim letters and done a comparison between having `32297` identical strutboxes the width of a letter, colored or not color (this is `xcolor` and color  `yellow`). Adding the colored boxes costs:

1. `195303` bytes when using dvipdfmx,
2. `232110` bytes when using pdflatex,
3. `194208` bytes when using pdflatex+`\pdfxform`.

It thus appears that `dvipdfmx` and `pdflatex+\pdfxform` are of the same efficiency and that each colored box costs about `6` bytes. I don't know why when this is done in file doing nothing else, the cost is more of `3.2` byte per colored box.

I have also observed something weird with `\pdfxform`. With this test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xcolor}    
\begin{document}

Hello.

%\fboxsep0pt

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}
  %{\colorbox{yellow}{\strut\phantom{X}}}
  {\strut\phantom{X}}% NO COLOR!

% USE OF \pdfxform

\pdfxform\mybox 

\count255 32297
\noindent\loop
\penalty0
\hbox{\pdfrefxform \pdflastxform}%
\advance\count255 by -1
\ifnum\count255>0
\repeat

\end{document}
```

I obtain circa `114000` bytes and about the same if the `\colorbox` is used. However if I *don't*  use the `\pdfxform` mechanism, then with colored boxes, the `pdf` weighs about `140000` bytes but when produced without color but only empty boxes it is then only `16572` bytes.

In my big file, using `\pdfxform` with colored boxes gives `951744` bytes, and using it with non-colored boxes `951711` bytes. Not using `pdfxform` however, then there is a big difference between colored (`953646` bytes) and non-colored cases (`721543` bytes).

Comment: Have you tried compressing of the resulting PDF?   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller/19047#19047

Comment: Have a look at `\pdfxform` etc. (section 7.8 of the pdfTeX manual).

Comment: I am not sure how rectangles ('boxes') are drawn in a PDF, but I am pretty sure that the corner coordinates are stored -- if there a lot of rectangles, I assume, that a lot of coordinates must be used.

Comment: @Daniel I have tried `ps2pdf` which is about the same as the direct `gs` invocation in the answer you linked to. I tried the invocation proposed there, and it gives the same result (file size increases from `1082657` bytes to over `1500000` bytes).

Comment: @MartinSchröder I will look at `\pdfxform`. I guess however this will compromise my preferred `dvipdfmx` route then ;-)

Comment: Load `xcolor` anyway :)

Comment: @percusse I omitted the information that my real use case is with `xcolor` indeed. I should have done the small tests here also with `xcolor`, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but I guess coordinates are needed the same way for letter glyphs? the `PDF` seems to be very efficient at re-using letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution using `\pdfxform`:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\colorbox{yellow}{\phantom{X}}}
\pdfxform0  \mathchardef\myboxnum=\pdflastxform
\def\mybox{\pdfrefxform\myboxnum}

\count255 4000
\noindent\loop
\mybox\
\advance\count255 by -1
\ifnum\count255>0
\repeat
```

The uncompressed PDF (`\pdfcompresslevel=0`) from your MWE has 673757 bytes and the same using `\pdfxform` has 170255 bytes, compress ratio is 3.95. The one yellow box created by your MWE looks in PDF like:

```
0 0 1 0 k 0 0 1 0 K
0 0 1 0 k 0 0 1 0 K
q
1 0 0 1 150.281 642.291 cm
0 0 13.45 12.785 re f
Q
0 0 1 0 k 0 0 1 0 K
0 g 0 G
0 0 1 0 k 0 0 1 0 K
0 g 0 G
0 g 0 G
0 g 0 G
```

It is evident that there is very uneffective color manipualtion (the macro package `color.sty` is responsible for this).

On the other hand, when `\pdfxform` is used, then the same yellow box is represented by:

```
q
1 0 0 1 150.281 642.291 cm
/Fm1 Do
Q
```

The pointer is used here. But the shift of the current point realized by concatenate matrix (cm) have to be applied for each box. On the other hand the printing of the character from font is more optimized in PDF specification: the current point between characters is shifted "automatically".

**Edit**: I did third experiment for comparison. To use colors manually without macro support in order to mimimalize the garbage in PDF:

```
\count255 4000
\noindent\loop
\hbox{\pdfliteral{0 0 1 0 k}\rlap{\vrule height2ex width.7em}\pdfliteral{0 g}\kern.7em}
\advance\count255 by -1
\ifnum\count255>0
\repeat
```

Now, the uncompressed PDF has 250322 bytes and one yellow box looks like:

```
1 0 0 1 10.205 0 cm
0 0 1 0 k
q
0 0 6.974 8.579 re f
Q
0 g
```

The compress ratio from MWE to this third solution is 2.7. Without using `\pdfxform`. Only uneffective macro package is omitted and colors are set by hand.

Comment: I have tried the `\pdfliteral`. However for my big document it gives a result not worse than using `\colorbox` only if I use the `\pdfxform` mechanism. There is then no gain compared to `\colorbox+\pdfxform` use. My files have compression: they are `PDF 1.5` files, as produced by default by `pdflatex` on my installation.