# Using Ghostscript to compress pdf with 3D content

Tags: pdf, asymptote, ghostscript, file-size

I have used Ghostscript to compress the pdf output of some large files as it seems to do a better job of getting rid of duplicate font information than Adobe Acrobat (which sometimes loses certain math glyphs). I use XeLaTeX and my documents contain lots of pdf graphics, each of which were also produced by XeLaTeX, all of which contain the Calibri font found on Windows.

The command I use is `gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf`, which I found in an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller).

My documents now include some interactive 3D graphics using the `\includemedia` command of the `media9` package. Each of these 3D graphics is created with Asymptote and are in the `.prc` format.

When I use the above Ghostscript command to compress the file, all the `.prc` information is lost - the 3D graphics are no longer interactive. I tried changing the compatibility level of the pdf to 1.7, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to use Ghostscript without losing the .prc information?

Comment: **Related question:** Is there a way to purposefully loose interactivity at the source code level to reduce the file size? This is especially interesting for people using PDF viewers that don't support `asymptote`'s interactive content in the first place.

Comment: @Casimir The way I handled this was to make a macro that inserted graphics, such as a `\myincludegraphics` command that responded to a Boolean `usethreeDgraphics`.  When this Boolean was `True`, then the image created also had the `.prc` information encoded (and the file size was larger). When this Boolean was `False`, my command `\myincludegraphics` just inserted a picture, and not the `.prc` information.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be `ghostscript` then maybe [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net) with `--compression-level=9 --recompress-flate` would be acceptable. You might need [other options](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html)