# What is going on with my PDFs filesize?

Tags: graphics

I have a LaTeX document with 4 images in it. I tried with PNGs (optimized with PNG Gauntlet: Total filesize 3.85 MB) and got a PDF with a filesize of 9.14 MB, which is getting rather large. I resaved the PNGs as JPEGs (Total filesize: 2.26 MB) and the PDF's filesize plummeted to 2.38 MB, barely larger then the images. I'd show the images, but I can't show them to anyone until publication, sorry.

Comment: Check this item which may be a duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller

Comment: @R.Schumacher I would say it is not: I'm not asking how to make the PDF smaller, I'm asking why the PNGs which are only 1.5 MB larger, cause a 7 MB increase in filesize.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Reading the answers, they mostly focus on font compression, which is obviously not the problem here.

Comment: Did you see the the discussion on page 41 of the pdftex manual (`texdoc pdftex`)? Interlaced PNGs require uncompressing them, which might be the cause of size increase.

Comment: @egreg I'll double check, but I was pretty certain I had these uninterlaced since it increases the file size.