# pdf file size of moderncv too large

Tags: pdftex, pdf, moderncv, file-size

When I `pdflatex` my `moderncv.tex` I obtain a file size of **150 kB**.
This seems too big since I don't include any picture yet. And in fact after

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
-sOutputFile=small.pdf moderncv.pdf
```

the file size is only **50 kB**.

So how can I obtain a similar file size right away with `pdflatex`?

I have already tried adding

```
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=3 
\pdfcompresslevel=9
```

But this only reduced the file size by about 1%.

Answer (score 2):

This extensive [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller) includes the most up-voted solution:

Many solutions exist ranging from the use of `gs` to `pdfsizeopt`. 
By Ghostscript (gs) to optimise and compress the PDF after its creation with pdflatex.

The suggested solution:

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```

providing up to 60/70% in size reduction.

Comment: @ georges I know this answer but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, and would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Not enough reputation to reply directly by comment. Edited the answer.