# A problem about inserting PDF file

Tags: pdfpages

I am using the following simple document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=.4]{horn1.pdf}
Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!
\end{document}
```

In the output file, 3 pages can be seen:

**First page:**

```
  Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!
```

**Second page:**

```
  PDF file
```

**Third page:**

```
   Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!
```

Using the command "scale=.4", I've reduced the PDF file size. Why can not I see the output file in a page?

Comment: Welcome:) You can search [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller) the needed

Comment: & Saravanan, Thanks, can you recommend a simple guide and shorter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the package `pdfpages`. `\includepdf` will always include the pdf as a separate page. Use `\includegraphics` with the `page` option instead, from the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!

\includegraphics[page=1,scale=.4]{horn1.pdf}

Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Just one more thing. Using {\centering \includegraphics[page=1,scale=.4]{horn1.pdf}}, PDF file dose not put in center palce. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: excuse me, I have another question. For example, if I want to use pages={1,3,5}, error occurs.  Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @Farid Regarding centering: I recommend to use `\begin{center}\includegraphics[...]{...}\end{center}`. If you want to use `\centering`, you have to include the end of the paragraph into the scope: `{\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}\par}` (or an empty line instead of `\par`).

Comment: @Farid Regarding `pages`: There is no `pages` option. An image consists of a single page only. If you want to include several pages, you have to use multiple `\includegraphics` commands (with different page numbers), and you have to arrange the images the way you want.

Comment: @Farid By the way, *there is always a specific reason* as long as the process is deterministic ;-) It may be hidden and not easy to discover, though.