# how to avoid latex builds from blowing up in size

Tags: pdftex, file-size

While in [1] the question is posed of how to make the pdfs produced by pdflatex smaller, and while answers are given therein. Here a different question is asked.

How can one avoid pdflatex from making a large pdf in the first place? Especially when one is including pdf files and image files in my build?

Here is a list of some useful links I am looking at:
[2]

If you have a particularly good link, please provide it.

Bibliography:

[1] [How to make the PDFs produced by pdfLaTeX smaller?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller)

[2] https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96szabo.pdf

Comment: You can consider adjusting `\pdfcompresslevel` and/or `\pdfobjcompresslevel`. Read more about it in the [pdfTeX user manual](//texdoc.net/pkg/pdftex).

Comment: I don't think your question is answerable in this generality. The obvious answers are include less text or fewer or lower resolution images. or subset the fonts rather than including the whole thing, but without any example how can we say? try using luatex rather than pdftex (it's usually slower but makes smaller pdf, but not always)

Answer (score 1):

I make sure to have all of my figures as `.pdf` instead of `.png` or `.jpg`. Making them vector allows them to be scaleable without the storage size becoming huge, and are < 200 kb in most cases. My (in-progress) PhD thesis is 14 MB with approximately 50 figures.