# Is it possible to reduce pdf file size by optimizing images in texniccenter?

Tags: pdf, file-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the PDFs produced by `pdflatex` smaller?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller)

I have some images in PNG. Those are large in size. I am editing using texniccenter, utilizing this pdflatex.exe.

Now, my question is, is there any way to tell the texniccenter to take those original (large)  PNG images and use resize it to a smaller size and then make the pdf?

Thank you.

Comment: You might need ImageMagick to resize the PNG file before invoking pdflatex. You need to create a batch file and configure the output profile of TeXnicCenter to call the batch.

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14429/5763) question.