# Avoiding compression artifacts when displaying results of image processing experiments

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, png

I'm creating a latex document in which I display results of some image processing experiments.  In particular, I'm displaying a black and white image which has been blurred (artifically) and then had noise added to it (artificially).  I want to make sure that I'm displaying this image correctly / in the standard way.  My goal is to completely avoid any compression artifacts when including images in a pdf file created using pdflatex.

Currently, I have a blurry, noisy image stored in a Matlab array called b of size 1024 by 1024.  The components of b are between 0 and 1.  I'm saving b as a png image using Matlab's imwrite command, as follows:

```
imwrite(b,'blurryNoisyImage.png','png')
```

First question: no compression is introduced in this step, right?

(Edit: Since b is an array of doubles with values between 0 and 1, there is a little precision lost here; I could get a slightly better result using 
imwrite(b,'blurryNoisyImage.png','png','bitdepth',16).)

I'm then including blurryNoisyImage.png in my .tex file, as shown in the following snippet of Latex:

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{blurryNoisyImage.png}
\caption{Blurry, noisy image.}
\end{subfigure}
```

I then use pdflatex to create a pdf file.  (And when I call pdflatex, I don't use any special commands telling pdflatex to avoid compression when creating the pdf file.)

Second question: could any compression artifacts be introduced at this step?

Please let me know if I'm doing this the standard way, and if there's a better way that I can do this!  Thank you!

Comment: I think PNG, by definition, uses lossless compression. If you want to make sure of this, use `imread` to read in a second copy of the image from your new PNG file, and compare it against the original variable `b`. As far as the final PDF goes, see [pdftex reduce PDF size: reduce image quality?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/pdftex-reduce-pdf-size-reduce-image-quality) and [How to make the PDFs produced by `pdflatex` smaller?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller) -- I think lossless is the default everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: why are you scaling the image `[width=\textwidth]` Given your concerns I'd have thought that you wanted to generate the bitmap at the desired size and then include it without scaling.