# How can I reduce the size of figures and/or the size of the final PDF document?

Tags: graphics, pdf, file-size

I usually include .pdf figures (vector graphics) in LaTeX files. The problem is that when I compile everything, the resulting file, which also has .pdf extension, is too large.

The size of the final PDF document is approximately equal to the sum of the size of the PDF document without figures plus the total size of the .pdf figures that are to be included.

Comment: Are the PDFs vector graphics, raster graphics, or what? Is the total size of the included PDFs approximately the same size as the final document?

Comment: Increasing the version of the PDF format helps with some size things but I don't know about this case. `\pdfminorversion=7` before `\documentclass` to test.

Comment: have you seen [pdftex reduce PDF size: reduce image quality?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14429) and the links within?

Comment: Can you create an `eps` version of one of your figures and make it available for download from somewhere? Sometimes it's possible to reduce the size of these without affecting the image quality.