# How to change image quality in a pdfTeX output and keep hyperlinks?

Tags: pdftex, ghostscript

I am trying to get a small PDF output from `pdftex`.

From [pdftex reduce PDF size: reduce image quality?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/pdftex-reduce-pdf-size-reduce-image-quality) I found the useful command

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=small.pdf big.pdf
```

that allows me to set the image resolution for the PDF. But this command removes all the document hyperlinks generated by `\cite` and `\ref` in LaTeX.

So, how can I decrease the PDF size but keep the hypertext information?

Comment: General compression of pdf  often degrades quality of image linework what is needed is an optimum value for included png by default they should be 96dpi at 1:1 such that a pixel is a bit thiner than 1pt if you calculate the include scale so that at 1:1 they are 96/72 inches then one pixel should be roughly 1 pt and linework acceptable if you get ratios right then there is no need to run additional GS or other conversion. It may need a bit of trial and error to get perfect results and a alternating pixel gridded image helps to see the effects but usually worth it.

Comment: YEs, this can be rech by `-xResolution=???` in `gs`. But running it the output PDF results without any hyperref.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `pdfa` option of hyperref. It sets a flag that prevents that links are lost.

The `pdfa` has more effects, but currently there is no way to set the flags independantly (but this can change in the future).

Comment: Using `\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}` made me get "Option clash for package hyperref".