# Re-saving with PDF comments decreases filesize of pdflatex output considerably. Why?

Tags: pdf

I'm producing some PDF weighting about 50 Mb. I just open it in my viewer, add a comment and save the file, then its size suddenly becomes about 30 mb.

What is happening? Am I loosing some important information in the process? And, if not, how do I produce a final PDF weighting the minimum using only PDFLaTeX?

Related: [pdf-printer-decreases-filesize-of-pdflatex-output-considerably-why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/pdf-printer-decreases-filesize-of-pdflatex-output-considerably-why)

Comment: I guess that when you insert some comment using your PDF viewer, after saving it, the resolution of graphics are being lowered.

Comment: Have you tried re-optimising your PDF using _e.g._ GhostScript? As pdfLaTeX creates the PDF 'as it goes' there are often optimisations to be made after-the-fact with all of the PDF structure known.

Comment: Would the following commands in the preamble help?
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=6 
\pdfcompresslevel=9

Comment: `\pdfminorversion=7`, even.

Comment: @Sigur, resolution doesn't change, this happens even without images (draft), and fonts keep vectorial.

Comment: @pluton and cfr answers work fine, size now gets increased by a little ammount when making some marks, as it happens usually with smaller projects. But, anyway, erasing the mark isn't resizing the file, I suppose it's a viewer's issue.

On the other hand, what is changing when adding, that commands? what am I loosing? viewer compatibility maybe?

Comment: And in fact the size reduction is negligible, and **it is only preventing the reduction when re-saving**!!