# What's most important if I want to produce a lightweight document?

Tags: file-size

If for some reason I want to create the lightest document (in terms of the weight of the output file, *not* the font), what would be some good practices? Specifically in terms of:

- **Packages**: do they add significant weight to the file? Are there some which are particularly heavy?
- **Graphics**: should they be EPS, PDF? Some other format? Is `TIKZ` code always lighter?
- **Classes**: do some add more bulk than others?
- (Some other important things I'm sure I'm missing...)

Of course I could just start trying to "play" with the above mentioned elements, but I was hoping to get an informed answer, not just the result of trial-and-error experiments.

Comment: What kind of a document do you have in mind?  For example, whether or not there are graphics can make a huge difference.

Comment: The smallest files tend to be those with nothing(!) but text in them; and the less text, the smaller the file.  [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/), however, can do wonders when it comes to shrinking the size of a PDF.  What are the constraints you have in mind; or, how much 'streamlining' do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Is it PDF file size you mean here?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-pdf-files-for-the-internet/

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I'm not thinking about a specific document - I just wanted to know some techniques and "best practices". The related topic posted by Torbjørn has some interesting answers, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as graphics go, you should use EPS or PDF, as they are vector graphics, which uses less space.  However, if you use PDF you must define a bounding box for the image, so it gets a little more complicated.

As far as shrinking the size of your file, I have found the best method is to use the "Reduce File Size" feature in acrobat pro (it is under the "document" menu).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that still doesn't answer all my questions.