# Why do some fonts used by siunitx and textcomp look rasterized?

Tags: fonts, siunitx, font-encodings, textcomp

For example, the mu in `\SI{1.55}{\micro\metre}` looks really bad for some reason.
For `textcomp`, `\textmu` looks the same.

Comment: That's weird. Same problem here. I paste an example compiled with texlive. http://tinypic.com/r/2hekgsx/7

Comment: That is weird... If you had a list of all the symbols that look rasterised, that might help solve the problem? The maintainer of siunitx is on this site, so I expect a good answer soon...

Comment: Install the cm-super fonts or use \usepackage{lmodern}.

Comment: @Ulrike: can you put that as an answer?

Comment: I tried with texlive 2010 (MacTeX) and it looks fine. Here's the version of siunitx: `{siunitx} {2010/07/15} {2.0n}`

Comment: @Yuppie, I second that.

Comment: Please detail which TeX system you are using: I never see this with a simple example document on any of the systems I have.

Comment: Also with texlive 2009 on linux I don't see any problems (the `\mu` is filling the screen!). The version of siunitx is `2009/09/21 v1.3a`.

Comment: I'm using TeXnicCenter with MiKTex. My siunitx package date is 2010-09-21. I can confirm that what Ulrike Fischer suggested worked for me. The symbols that looked odd were usually the upright greek symbols. I used the lmodern package and everything looks fine now.

Comment: The author of `siunitx` should be notified. This must be a bug. I have the last version

Comment: Well, I am the author of `siunitx`, and on my system don't see this. Thus it is down to the fonts installed in your system (`siunitx` uses the same glyph `\textmu` symbol from `textcomp`, but in a private internal version.) As I said, on my system everything is included properly and scales nicely.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that, as Joseph suggested, \textmu from the textcomp package also has a the same poor quality font if the lmodern package isn't used or the cm-super fonts are not installed. Changed title to include textcomp.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Sorry I accused you, I checked and you are right. The problem is in `textcomp`. My version is texlive 2010.19888 on Arch Linux

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer could you write up your comment as an answer so we can get this question of the unanswered list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turning Ulrike Fischer's comment into an answer: This happens because you are using the type 3 versions of the TS1 encoded fonts that are accessed via the `textcomp` package. There are 2 simple ways to resolve this.

- Install the cm-super fonts, via whichever mechanism your TeX distribution allows (these fonts are very standard and should be available for every major TeX distribution, but since they are quite large they are not always installed by default).
- Put `\usepackage{lmodern}` in the document preamble, to use the Latin Modern fonts.

Both of these options should fix the problem of using type 3 symbols, and should have only very minor effects on the rest of the document. The first option should only change the problematic glyphs; the second option will also cause very slight changes to the whole document (you may or may not view these as improvements, or you may not even notice since the difference is very subtle).

See [Latin Modern vs cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390/627) for some tips on the difference between `lmodern` and cm-super.

See [Finding ‘8-bit’ Type 1 fonts](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-type1T1) on the UK TUG FAQ for some more background.

Comment: I'd been toying with posting Ulrike's comment as an answer also, but I thought she might return and do so herself :-)