# Why aren't there well-hinted Type1 Computer Modern fonts supporting the T1 encoding yet?

Tags: fonts, pdf, font-encodings

Given the popularity of PDF, the pain that is OT1, and the bad on-screen rendering of bitmapped fonts in Adobe's software, I would have expected that someone would have undertaken conversion/extension of the BlueSky fonts to the T1 encoding while maintaining the quality of the hints ... but I've seen nothing about such a project anywhere.

Why is that? (Or am I wrong? I would love to be wrong!)

### Edit:

Now I've seen that someone is selling European Computer Modern fonts in Type1(?), and evidently they use T1 -- but why are they not free yet?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but it seems to me that you should accept more answers to your questions.  This is in part a courtesy to those who respond, but also helps guide later readers to the response you consider best.

Comment: @Ryan: Okay, working on it... Sometimes it is hard to decide which answer to accept.

Comment: In that situation, if all the answers are equally useful to you, then just toss a coin. But don't leave your answerers without their due thanks and feedback, and the rest of us without a guiding light!

Answer (score 5):

read the [web page](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) of the font project "The Latin Modern (LM) Family of Fonts" and the [demo page](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodern/)

Comment: Hmm, those are perhaps close, but (a) they have incompatible metrics and (b) I have been [given to understand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super/1396#1396) that they are not very well hinted for on-screen rendering. The hinting does seem to have improved somewhat since [http://dw.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf](http://dw.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf), but the stems still look uneven to me in [the demo PDF](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodern/lmodern.pdf) at 96 dpi with Adobe Reader 9.4.1.