# Text font matching CM Math?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I see many people ask about a math font to match their favorite text font. Here I'm asking the inverse question. When I first heard about LaTeX, I was so impressed by its super high quality output, especially, when writing math. The default CM math font, IMHO, is the best I have seen (even better than some of the commercial math fonts). It has minor problems, which I see many good hacks here for most of them.

So, my question is: are there any text fonts, which best match CM math font? CM text font is too light in print and it became too old. Many experts also criticize the use of `Times` with CM math. I have been searching for some time for a solution without much success. Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Have you taken a look at the posting [Suggest a "nice" font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001)? If CM Roman is too light, in your opinion, you should probably look for *matched* text and math fonts that are *both* a bit darker than CM. If you choose a text font that's noticeably darker than CM Math, you'll just get a new mis-match.

Comment: Well, CM was designed to work with CM maths. If you object to it on grounds of age, why not CM maths for the same reason? Latin Modern provides maths and text fonts, and are based on the CM fonts. `lmodern` or `cfr-lm` support those. That is, I kind of doubt you'll find something which works better than the fonts they are designed to use. And you should be using the same font in maths for text as you do for body text, so mixing in something else is unlikely to blend as well as the originals. That is, switch neither or switch both, or the results are unlikely to be good.

Comment: @Mico Sure, I read that. But I see only CM text with CM math. I know they are the best match, but, I'm searching for a very near alternative to CM text because it is only too light on both screen and print.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to look through [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). Plus [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110772/8528) is neat. (Never used it myself, however.)