# How to obtain a heavier math font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

The current question is a follow-up to some previously asked questions, like this: [It is possible to make fonts appear heavier (darker) in pdf output of Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110569/it-is-possible-to-make-fonts-appear-heavier-darker-in-pdf-output-of-latex/110772#110772) and this: [Make entire document heavier using pdfrender](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110988/make-entire-document-heavier-using-pdfrender?lq=1) and this: [Fake bold in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102578/fake-bold-in-lualatex/102706#102706). All of these questions deal with the document as a whole (equally text and math). In my case, I need to make only math font a bit thicker (darker). I use `times` for text and `CM` for math. The former is much heavier than the latter and they just look horrible. My goal then is to make `CM` math a little bit darker to shorten that gap. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I add a not-so-minimal working example here showing my real usage as asked by some commentators. I use MiKTeX on Windows and I run `pdflatex` directly to obtain a `pdf` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,table]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[indention=10pt,position=top,margin=0pt,font=small,
            labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,skip=6pt,hypcap=false,
            labelfont=bf,list=true,textfont=sf]
            {subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,calc,longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor,multirow}
\usepackage{tocbibind}  % Show all lot, lof, loa, refs. in TOC
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\lhead{\itshape \chaptername ~\thechapter}
\rhead{\itshape \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}% remove "Chapter N." prefix
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Title Here and authorship
\end{titlepage}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Dedication}
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\chapter{Abstract}
\clearpage
  {%
    \singlespacing 
    \tableofcontents 
  }%
\clearpage
%========================= List of Figures ============================= 
\listoffigures
\clearpage
%=========================== List of Tables ============================ 
\listoftables 
\clearpage
%======================= List of Abbreviations ========================= 
\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
\clearpage
%================================ List of Symbols======================= 
\chapter{List of Symbols}
\clearpage
%================================ Main Chapters ======================== 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First Section}
Some text which is OK! and some math which is so light:

\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}
\begin{split}
H_c &=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}
\end{equation}

%========================== Additonal Appendices ======================= Appendices
\appendix
\clearpage
%====================== References Section ============================= 
\setstretch{1}
\begin{thebibliography}{199} % 199 is a random guess of the total number of references
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\mathbf` and `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: Check the LaTeX Font Catalogue, specifically the [Fonts with math support](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html). Choosing any of these will show you examples of text, maths, and available styles.

Comment: @Andrew - And how to differentiate between bold and non-bold?

Comment: @erik - I searched that Catalogue, but I'm not satisfied with any of the choices there. I'm looking for a new way to define math font as the attempts in the links of my question.

Comment: Since you're using Times as the text font, is there a reason for not using Times as the math font as well?

Comment: You might use `fourier` which defines a math version of Adobe Utopia. It has been extenede for text by `erewhon`, which brings real smallcapts in 4 versions, oldstyle numbers and inferior and superior figures. The `mathdesign` package defines math  versions for Utopia, URW Garamond (extended by Garamondx) and Bitstream Charter (extended by xCharter).

Comment: @Mico - To my knowledge, their is no good non-commercial package which can provide good `Times` math fonts.

Comment: @AboAmmar - Have you checked out the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages? They're definitely free, as is tge `mathptmx` package?

Comment: @Mico - Yes, these are the nearest to me, but, they still have some problems. Just to mention some: large symbols are a bit strange, `\int`, `\sum`, `\pi`, `\sigma`, ... are also not appealing to the eye.

Comment: Those will work better with Times than CM. It is not going to be easier to fake darker CM for maths than it was for text.... Plus, you will have the inevitable mismatch to contend with.

Comment: There is also TeX Gyre Termes which comes with a math font too and STIX or XITS.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The problem is I have no choice for text but `Times`.

Comment: You can just load the math fonts from these.  Which engine are you using? How are you loading "Times"?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'm using `pdflatex` and I load `times` by issuing`\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the extra info and provide a MWE.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ok, I edited my question

Comment: The standard solution would be to `\usepackage{mathptmx}` which sets `\rmdefault` to `ptm` and does some appropriate font substitutions in the math.  However, `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are regarded as more modern and complete versions of this.

Answer (score 6):

Comptuer Modern is intentionally light.  It is better to choose a math font corresponding to your main text.

There is a package `mathptmx` in the psnfss bundle that sets the main text to `ptm` and fakes some corresponding math fonts.  Using this gives better results than you are seeing.  However, better would be to switch to a more modern solution provided by the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.  Below are examples of each.

## `mathptmx`

[image: Sample mathptmx]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,table]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First Section}
Some text which is OK! and some math which is the same weight:

\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}
\begin{split}
H_c &=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

## `newtxtext` with `newtxmath`

[image: Sample newtx]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,table]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[helvratio=0.92]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First Section}
Some text which is OK! and some math which is the same weight:

\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}
\begin{split}
H_c &=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at the mathtime (mtpro2) fonts.  The fonts are commercial, but one only has to pay for the full set, which most people don't need.  The fonts are better in some ways (eg kerning) than some alternatives.

Comment: ,@JPi I already know about `mtpro2` and use it some times in less-math demanding documents, but, this is a long document with heavy math (vectors, bold Capital Greek symbols, ...), so, the `lite` version of `mtpro2` will be by no means sufficient.

Comment: ok.  (I've paid the $75.)