# Making everything in the document thicker

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize, math-fonts

The problem is how to make everything in a document slightly thicker.

My starting point was spurred by Computer Modern, which I would like to make thicker. In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110988/make-entire-document-heavier-using-pdfrender), the problem was almost solved via `pdfrender` or alternatively `\pdfliteral`. The remaining problem is that horizontal lines in math are unaffected.

However, the answer to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/how-can-i-put-a-coloured-outline-around-fraction-lines) suggests that `contour` could be used to make the remaining parts of the document thicker. Essentially, this is mainly showing in fractions and the horizontal line of the square root sign.

Is there a way to “automatize” the process of applying `contour` (or the technique used by it) to those remaining parts of the document or, for that matter, everywhere, without the need of `pdfrender`?

As an alternative solution, we may apply poor man's bold to the entire pdf. Is it possible?

Comment: The funny thing is that minus signs, equality signs, and arrows, all become thicker. It's probably something related to extensible horizontal lines...

Comment: Fonts are very delicate things, that were usually designed very carefully. Don't try to alter them in that crude fashion. There are more than enough good fonts out there (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/), just pick one that meets your needs and use it

Comment: seem that the [xfakebold](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfakebold) package make what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, xfakebold does not make fractions and the horizontal line in the square root sign bold... am I missing something?