# How to use Latin Modern for text and Latin Modern Math for math

Tags: pdftex, latin-modern

How do I switch from the default Computer Modern for text and math to Latin Modern for text and Latin Modern Math for math?

In the preamble I put  `\usepackage{lmodern}` to switch to Latin Modern for text.  But what should I add to the preamble so that the document uses Latin Modern Math for math?

The Latin Modern Math download page seems to be for downloading the font for use with MS Word or Adobe or something.

Comment: You get also the math fonts, but I recommend also loading `fixcmex` in order to overcome a glitch of `lmodern`.

Comment: What's the glitch?

Comment: Try with `\sum` in a subscript. Do it with `amsmath` loaded, with and without `lmodern`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `pdflatex`, then just

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

will *completely* replace Computer Modern with Latin Modern for text and math, because its code is

```
\ProvidesPackage{lmodern}[2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts]

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}

\DeclareOption{nomath}{\endinput}
\DeclareOption{variablett}{%
  \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmvtt}
}
\DeclareOption{lighttt}{%
  \let\lmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal}{OML}{lmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {OT1}{lmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}  {OML}{lmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}  {OMS}{lmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}  {OT1}{lmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}  {OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}

\def\mathsterling{\mathit{\mathchar"70BF}}
```

However, when used in combination with `amsmath` it has a problem: with `amsmath` (and no font package), the `largesymbols` font is scalable, but with `lmodern` it becomes fixed size.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\[
X_{\sum_i a_i}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment the `\usepackage{lmodern}` line you get

[image]

which is unacceptable. The usage of a fixed font size for `largesymbols` has other nasty consequences, so I recommend adding `\usepackage{fixcmex}` (that was written exactly for solving this problem). It will revert the `largesymbols` font to Computer Modern, precisely `cmex10` and other sizes, but `lmex10` is a straightforward copy if `cmex10`, so there will be essentially no difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}

\begin{document}

\[
X_{\sum_i a_i}
\]

\end{document}
```

*Don't* load `lmodern` if you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. If you use these engines, the default font is Latin Modern (with Computer Modern for math) even if you don't load `fontspec`; loading also `unicode-math` will use Latin Modern Math.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the actual font named Latin Modern Math, which is an OpenType font, you need LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  Add

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

You do not need any other commands or packages.  You can, if you feel like it, additionally set

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
```

However, these are already the default in `unicode-math`.

You do not need to use `lmodern`, or any other legacy 8-bit font package, along with `unicode-math`.  All they will do is waste a very tiny amount of time.

Comment: Perfect for Xe- or LuaLaTeX

Comment: @UngarLinski I assumed you literally meant the font named Latin Modern Math.

Comment: I did.  I mean that the unicode-math package does not work with pdfLaTeX.  It loads and runs perfectly on Xe- or LuaLaTeX.  I was not clear in my original post that I was running pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a minimal working example in `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`. You can see the `\mathcal` and `\mathbb` are differents from by default of `CM`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=lm]
\begin{document}
This is a short formula
\[abc\sum_{i=0}^Na_i=\mathcal{C}\mathbb{R}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addendum:

In this link you can see the union between Latin modern text and math.

https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/latinmodernroman/

Comment: I'm using pdflatex.  Does that matter?  And the text part of your example is Latin Modern?

Comment: I have not seen the pdfLaTeX tag. Yes of course it is the same of computer modern (CM).

Comment: Just to clarify:  The text is Latin Modern but the math is Latin Modern Math?

Comment: @UngarLinski with pdflatex you just need `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @UngarLinski Yes! It is the same with some differences. You can see my comment to begin of my answer. I add also a related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25418/use-case-for-latin-modern-math-lm-math