# pgfplots barplots doesn't build

Tags: pgfplots

I have slight problem with pgfplots barplot. What I am trying to build is relatively simple, and for the life of me I can't see where my error is. The funny thing is that when I try to compile with the pgfplot code, I get all sorts of citation errors..... commenting pgfplots code out and compilign again, everything works and no errors.

The pgfplots code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      width=.8\linewidth,
      height=7cm,
      title=Flutningstakmarkanir yfir spátímabilið,
      xlabel={Sviðsmyndir},
      ylabel={Milljón \$ },
      symbolic x coords={Mynd 1,Mynd 2, Mynd 3},
      xtick=data,
      legend columns=-1, % to set one line legend
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=center},
      ymajorgrids
      ]
      \addplot+[ybar] coordinates { (mynd1,98) (mynd2,59) (mynd3,43)};
      \addplot+[ybar] coordinates { (mynd1,95) (mynd2,57) (mynd3,42)};
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

All of the packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}



% Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}} % Add Table of Contents to PDF "bookmark" table of contents
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

% Blue color according to HÍ corporate design
\convertcolorspec{RGB}{16,9,159}{rgb}\tmphiblue
\definecolor{hiblue}{rgb}\tmphiblue


\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\raggedbottom

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\itshape}
\setkomafont{caption}{\itshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\FloatBarrier\Large}
\setcapwidth{\textwidth}
%\setcapwidth[l]{\textwidth} % The original template had the [l] which leads to a warning that it gets ignored, so to reduce warnings, removed it.
\setcapindent{1em}


\usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern (instead of the default Computer Modern that is rendered using a bitmap font).
\usepackage{fixcmex} % To fix that Latin Modern large symbol math fonts has by default only one size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621536
% Times new roman font instead of the standard LaTeX fonts: has not been test -- try this on your own risk
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Configurations (Useful defaults, but OK to change %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{figs/}} % Figures in directory figs

% Bibliography

% \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % Uncoment if you want to used NatBib instead of BibLaTeX (and comment the bitlatex line below)

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}  % BibLaTeX used for references. 
\usepackage{csquotes} % BibLaTex wants to have context sensitive quotes
\addbibresource{references.bib} %  Name of *.bib file containing references
```

I do have pgfplots line plot set up in a similar way that works very beautifully. Most of the articles I look up have the pgfplots code set up in similar matter. I only want to use my language for labes, titles and stuff like that.
If someone could point me to my error, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: The names in `symbolic x coords` should be the same as in `coordinates`. otherwise you get error  `coordinate ... is unknow,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), i.e. a small but complete document which reproduce your problem, not two code fragments (see an example below)
- as I said in comment, the names in`symbolic x coords` should be the same as are used in `coordinates` at `\addplot`
  . an example of MWE, which produce desired diagram:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=.8\linewidth,   height=7cm,
    ymajorgrids,
    title=Flutningstakmarkanir yfir spátímabilið,
enlarge x limits = 0.25,    % <--- added
    ybar,
    xlabel={Sviðsmyndir},
    ylabel={Milljón \$ },
      xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords = {A, B, C},
    legend columns=-1, % to set one line legend
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=center},
      ]
\addplot coordinates { (A,98) (B,59) (C,43)};   % <---
\addplot coordinates { (A,95) (B,57) (C,42)};   % <---
\legend{text 1, text 2}     % <--- added
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- that use of symbol coordinates is more clear, i change thewir names to A, B and C. However, you can change them to what you wish, but remember, the same names you should use in `symbolic x coords` and in `coordinates`.
- I a wee bet shorten your code, changes are marked in code by `% <---`

[image]

Comment: Oh god!!!! Couln't notice this slight difference in the namign in `symbolic x coord` and `coordinates`.

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, it happens :-). I have to admit that I observed  differences until after a while ... Happy TeXing!