# Need some help fitting large table in one page not using resizebox

Tags: tables, footnotes, page, resize

Thanks to this amazing community here I have gotten pretty far with my thesis document, but this problem has had me scratching my head for a while. I have only been able to use `\resizebox` for this table. That however messes up with the footnote I need to use and renders it quite strange.

I have tried `\longtable` package, but when I tried that with this table, I got an `undefined control sequense` pointing me to `\end{longtable}`. There might be some package michmach causing that.

I have also tried to use `tabularray` package, with `siunitx`, but `siunitx` throws up an error telling me it can't read the numbers in my table. That is probably due to some PATH issues. I haven't been able to pinpoint that out. I did delete all TexLive and LaTeX packages I could find on my system and reinstalled all of the packages, but it did not work. Due to time shortage, I am not going to follow up more on this error.

I do not want to render this table in landscape.
Now few of these headings are quite long, but due to nature of my native language and what information I am trying to come across, it is not possible to shorten them, so wraping is essential.

Here are all the packages and the table in entirety:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
% \usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}
% \usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{placeins}
% \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern (instead of the default Computer Modern that is rendered using a bitmap font).
\usepackage{fixcmex} % To fix that Latin Modern large symbol math fonts has by default only one size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621536
% Times new roman font instead of the standard LaTeX fonts: has not been test -- try this on your own risk
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}  % BibLaTeX used for references. 
\usepackage{csquotes} % BibLaTex wants to have context sensitive quotes

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering
      {\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}
      \caption{Spá um raforkunotkun, forgangsorka og skerðanleg orka. Almenn notkun að meðtöldum dreifitöpum og núverandi og samþykktir nýir stórnotendur. \label{table:Orkuspá}}
      \scriptsize\tabcolsep=2pt
      \resizebox{!}{.31\paperheight}{
      \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{NiceTabular}{lcccccccccc}
    \hline
    \Block{2-1}{Ár} & \Block{1-2}{Úttekt frá dreifikerfinu\\ forgangs- og skerðanleg\\ orka með dreifitöpum} & & \Block{1-2}{Úttekt frá\\ flutningskerfinu} & & \Block{1-2}{Flutningstöp} & & \Block{1-2}{Úttekt frá \\ vinnslufyrirtækjum} & & \Block{1-2}{Samtals} \\
    & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW  \\
    \hline
    2015 \tnote{*} & 3.604,74 & 618,46 & 14.356,34 & 1.685,89 & 369,56 & 57,11 & 468,32 & 75,40 & 18.798,96 & 2.383,25 \\
    2016 \tnote{*} & 3.383,99 & 590,10 & 14.334,19 & 1.695,96 & 360,42 & 57,05 & 470,86 & 71,46 & 18.549,46 & 2.378,51 \\
    2017 \tnote{*} & 3.519,13 & 608,86 & 14.869,95 & 1.750,87 & 373,07 & 61,49 & 476,38 & 84,74 & 19.238,53 & 2.443,61 \\
    2018 \tnote{*} & 3.682,07 & 623,26 & 15.259,88 & 1.838,28 & 398,09 & 70,47 & 489,75 & 70,71 & 19.829,79 & 2.519,53 \\
    2019 \tnote{*} & 3.506,86 & 596,63 & 15.145,31 & 1.829,48 & 365,82 & 63,40 & 476,84 & 85,11 & 19.494,83 & 2.495,07 \\
    2020 \tnote{*} & 3.473,77 & 596,83 & 14.830,70 & 1.790,95 & 353,09 & 60,54 & 469,74 & 72,27 & 19.127,30 & 2.408,28 \\
    2021 & 3.688,10 & 630,47 & 15.539,59 & 1.865,64 & 397,70 & 67,72 & 479,82 & 73,82 & 20.105,21 & 2.584,89 \\
    2022 & 3.785,98 & 647,81 & 16.099,28 & 1.875,76 & 416,40 & 69,68 & 490,14 & 75,41 & 20.791,80 & 2.615,29 \\
    2023 & 3.901,70 & 668,25 & 16.260,20 & 1.893,98 & 427,58 & 70,34 & 500,66 & 77,02 & 21.090,13 & 2.655,40 \\
    2024 & 3.991,75 & 684,32 & 16.325,85 & 1.899,97 & 436,37 & 70,59 & 511,28 & 78,66 & 21.265,25 & 2.678,87 \\
    2025 & 4.062,50 & 697,11 & 16.343,42 & 1.903,47 & 443,82 & 70,62 & 521,72 & 80,27 & 21.371,46 & 2.696,43 \\
    2026 & 4.122,77 & 708,12 & 16.343,42 & 1.903,47 & 450,61 & 70,54 & 526,76 & 81,04 & 21.443,55 & 2.707,91 \\
    2027 & 4.211,88 & 724,11 & 16.343,42 & 1.903,47 & 458,05 & 70,57 & 531,45 & 81,76 & 21.544,79 & 2.724,32 \\
    2028 & 4.296,04 & 739,29 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 465,42 & 70,58 & 536,08 & 82,47 & 21.640,51 & 2.739,90 \\
    2029 & 4.411,85 & 759,94 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 473,55 & 70,71 & 540,85 & 83,21 & 21.769,21 & 2.760,98 \\
    2030 & 4.532,38 & 781,44 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,86 & 70,86 & 545,67 & 83,95 & 21.902,87 & 2.782,93 \\
    2031 & 4.620,14 & 795,89 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,69 & 70,84 & 550,32 & 84,66 & 21.995,11 & 2.797,77 \\
    2032 & 4.717,78 & 812,01 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,73 & 70,84 & 555,02 & 85,39 & 22.097,48 & 2.814,28 \\
    2033 & 4.812,21 & 827,55 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,67 & 70,83 & 559,78 & 86,12 & 22.196,62 & 2.830,22 \\
    2034 & 4.902,86 & 842,42 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,51 & 70,81 & 564,68 & 86,87 & 22.292,01 & 2.845,50 \\
    2035 & 4.989,20 & 856,51 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,24 & 70,77 & 569,72 & 87,65 & 22.383,12 & 2.860,04 \\
    2036 & 5.072,75 & 870,11 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 480,89 & 70,72 & 574,87 & 88,44 & 22.471,48 & 2.874,09 \\
    2037 & 5.152,14 & 882,97 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 480,43 & 70,65 & 580,05 & 89,24 & 22.555,59 & 2.887,41 \\
    2038 & 5.228,32 & 895,26 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,89 & 70,57 & 585,32 & 90,05 & 22.636,49 & 2.900,17 \\
    2039 & 5.302,08 & 907,11 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,29 & 70,48 & 590,68 & 90,87 & 22.715,00 & 2.912,50 \\
    2040 & 5.405,41 & 924,00 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,30 & 70,49 & 596,13 & 91,71 & 22.823,81 & 2.929,88 \\
    2041 & 5.478,79 & 935,75 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 478,65 & 70,39 & 601,62 & 92,56 & 22.902,03 & 2.942,12 \\
    2042 & 5.552,10 & 947,46 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 477,99 & 70,29 & 607,11 & 93,40 & 22.980,15 & 2.954,33 \\
    2043 & 5.626,68 & 959,37 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 477,33 & 70,20 & 612,60 & 94,25 & 23.059,57 & 2.966,73 \\
    2044 & 5.703,24 & 971,59 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 476,71 & 70,10 & 618,20 & 95,11 & 23.141,10 & 2.979,47 \\
    2045 & 5.782,58 & 984,27 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 476,12 & 70,02 & 623,90 & 95,98 & 23.225,56 & 2.992,67 \\
    2046 & 5.864,53 & 997,37 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 475,58 & 69,94 & 629,65 & 96,87 & 23.312,72 & 3.006,30 \\
    2047 & 5.948,06 & 1.010,72 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 475,05 & 69,86 & 635,38 & 97,75 & 23.401,45 & 3.020,16 \\
    2048 & 6.033,38 & 1.024,34 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 474,54 & 69,79 & 641,24 & 98,65 & 23.492,13 & 3.034,33 \\
    2049 & 6.119,59 & 1.038,10 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 474,03 & 69,71 & 647,11 & 99,56 & 23.583,69 & 3.048,62 \\
    2050 & 6.207,13 & 1.052,06 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 473,53 & 69,64 & 653,00 & 100,46 & 23.676,62 & 3.063,11 \\
    2051 & 6.298,36 & 1.067,52 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 475,50 & 69,93 & 658,16 & 101,26 & 23.774,98 & 3.079,33 \\
    2052 & 6.389,36 & 1.082,94 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 477,46 & 70,22 & 663,38 & 102,06 & 23.873,16 & 3.095,51 \\
    2053 & 6.479,88 & 1.098,29 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,42 & 70,50 & 668,64 & 102,87 & 23.970,91 & 3.111,63 \\
    2054 & 6.569,42 & 1.113,46 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,35 & 70,79 & 673,96 & 103,69 & 24.067,70 & 3.127,58 \\
    2055 & 6.657,82 & 1.128,44 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 483,27 & 71,07 & 679,34 & 104,51 & 24.163,39 & 3.143,35 \\
    2056 & 6.744,86 & 1.143,20 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 485,15 & 71,35 & 684,76 & 105,35 & 24.257,74 & 3.158,90 \\
    2057 & 6.830,19 & 1.157,66 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 487,01 & 71,62 & 690,25 & 106,19 & 24.350,41 & 3.174,16 \\
    2058 & 6.913,30 & 1.171,75 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 488,82 & 71,88 & 695,78 & 107,04 & 24.440,86 & 3.189,06 \\
    2059 & 6.993,67 & 1.185,37 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 490,57 & 72,14 & 701,37 & 107,90 & 24.528,57 & 3.203,51 \\
    2060 & 7.071,89 & 1.198,63 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 492,28 & 72,39 & 707,02 & 108,77 & 24.614,16 & 3.217,60 \\
    \textbf{2061} & \textbf{7.172,96} & \textbf{1.214,87} & \textbf{16.398,49} & \textbf{1.907,18} & \textbf{496,07} & \textbf{71,07} & \textbf{712,49} & \textbf{109,61} & \textbf{24.780,01} & \textbf{3.236,67} \\
    \textbf{2062} & \textbf{7.258,87} & \textbf{1.229,10} & \textbf{16.402,60} & \textbf{1.907,46} & \textbf{497,27} & \textbf{71,09} & \textbf{717,97} & \textbf{110,46} & \textbf{24.876,71} & \textbf{3.251,74} \\
    \textbf{2063} & \textbf{7.344,78} & \textbf{1.243,34} & \textbf{16.406,71} & \textbf{1.907,73} & \textbf{498,47} & \textbf{71,12} & \textbf{723,45} & \textbf{111,30} & \textbf{24.973,41} & \textbf{3.266,82} \\
    \textbf{2064} & \textbf{7.430,69} & \textbf{1.257,57} & \textbf{16.410,81} & \textbf{1.908,01} & \textbf{499,67} & \textbf{71,14} & \textbf{728,94} & \textbf{112,14} & \textbf{25.070,11} & \textbf{3.281,89} \\
    \textbf{2065} & \textbf{7.516,60} & \textbf{1.271,80} & \textbf{16.414,92} & \textbf{1.908,29} & \textbf{500,87} & \textbf{71,17} & \textbf{734,42} & \textbf{112,99} & \textbf{25.166,80} & \textbf{3.296,96} \\
    \textbf{2066} & \textbf{7.602,51} & \textbf{1.286,04} & \textbf{16.419,02} & \textbf{1.908,56} & \textbf{502,07} & \textbf{71,20} & \textbf{739,90} & \textbf{113,83} & \textbf{25.263,50} & \textbf{3.312,04} \\
    \textbf{2067} & \textbf{7.688,41} & \textbf{1.300,27} & \textbf{16.423,13} & \textbf{1.908,84} & \textbf{503,27} & \textbf{71,22} & \textbf{745,39} & \textbf{114,67} & \textbf{25.360,20} & \textbf{3.327,11} \\
    \textbf{2068} & \textbf{7.772,08} & \textbf{1.313,81} & \textbf{16.395,02} & \textbf{1.907,70} & \textbf{502,13} & \textbf{71,14} & \textbf{750,25} & \textbf{115,42} & \textbf{25.456,90} & \textbf{3.342,18} \\
    \textbf{2069} & \textbf{7.855,96} & \textbf{1.327,38} & \textbf{16.387,86} & \textbf{1.906,81} & \textbf{501,46} & \textbf{71,14} & \textbf{755,25} & \textbf{116,19} & \textbf{25.553,60} & \textbf{3.357,25} \\
    \textbf{2070} & \textbf{7.940,94} & \textbf{1.341,16} & \textbf{16.386,68} & \textbf{1.906,59} & \textbf{500,99} & \textbf{71,16} & \textbf{760,41} & \textbf{116,99} & \textbf{25.650,29} & \textbf{3.372,33} \\
    \textbf{2071} & \textbf{8.026,03} & \textbf{1.354,96} & \textbf{16.388,08} & \textbf{1.906,60} & \textbf{500,68} & \textbf{71,19} & \textbf{765,78} & \textbf{117,81} & \textbf{25.746,99} & \textbf{3.387,40} \\
    \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \item[*]Rauntölur 
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am not very experienced with LaTeX, and I don't know which packages play badly or well with other.
If it is possible to cram this table in one page without rezisebox, I am all ears, but if not, then this is only in appendix.

Edit: 20023-04-26(YYYY-MM-DD)
Tried to put up `tabularx` environment, got an error `missing number: treated as zero` at `\begin{tabularx}`. Uncomment `\usepackage{tabularx}` from code above. Here is how I call the funciton:

```
\begin{table}
      \centering
      \caption{one more time}
      \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{tabularx}{*{11}{X}}
      \toprule
THE TABLE FROM ABOVE
\bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
      \begin{tablenotes}
  \item[*]Rauntölur 
  \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Off-topic: It makes no sense to load the `lmodern` font package and then to clobber it with the `mathptmx` font package.

Comment: I **think** those two packages were put up by the University. I'll see if I can get by, by commenting out `mathptmx`

Comment: I'd have the column units on a line of their own (usually listed as `(MWh)` etc). That saves a lot of space. Next use `\footnotesize` instead of `\small`. Then it actually fits within the line width. I don't think `NiceTabular` and `threeparttable` plays that well with each other especially with that like with the `\Block`'s are being used.

Comment: @daleiff The `MWh` and `MW` are on a special line. I'll try changing to `\footnotesize`. What would you use instead of `NiceTabular`? Regular `tabular` or `tabularx`?

Comment: The MWh's are not on a special line in your example, I'd split them from Orka and Afl. I'm not familiar with how NIceTabular works but I'd try `tabularx`

Comment: @daleif I have tried changing `NiceTabular` to `tabular` and `tabularx`. Both provide me with an error on `\end{threeparttable}`. For `tabular` it is `undefined control sequense`, and for `tabularx` I get `Missing number, treated as zero`.

Comment: Sounds like you're not invoking the `tabularx` environment correctly. Please show the code you use to invoke a tabularx env.

Comment: You mean `\begin{tabularx}{XXXXXXXXXXX}` (11 X because I have 11 columns) and `end{tabularx`? I am fairly new and I am not sure what you mean by "Invoke `tabularx` environment"... **Sorry, I just noticed that I forgot to uncomment `\usepackage{tabularx}`, my mistake**.... _had not effect, I literally just swapped `NiceTabular` out for `tabularx`_

Comment: In situations like this I'd prefer to use the `tabularray` package. Its *talltable* and *longtable* options are designed for these tables. Plus it uses `booktabs` and `siunitx` as libraries.

Comment: I tried `tabularray` and `siunitx` doesn't work for me, probably due to some $PATH problem, as mentioned in my post.

Comment: I just compiled the complete code you gave above. It doesn't generate an error when I use either PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I use MikTeX 23.4 and TeXStudio 4.40 on Windows 11 22H2.

Comment: What error dit `siunitx` give you? I doubt it is $PATH$ related, but this is just a guess ...

Comment: @alchemist The error I get when I use `siunitx` is something along not being able to read the first number in the table. I have no idea how to troubleshoot that. My TexLive-latexextra has alsmot all packages available, as seen [here](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-latexextra/files/), I am using GNOME-Latex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145613/discussion-between-olafur-vidir-gudbjargarson-and-alchemist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provisional answer as code can't be uploaded in *Chat*:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern (instead of the default Computer Modern that is rendered using a bitmap font).
\usepackage{fixcmex} % To fix that Latin Modern large symbol math fonts has by default only one size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621536

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}  % BibLaTeX used for references. 
\usepackage{csquotes} % BibLaTex wants to have context sensitive quotes

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx,varwidth}
\sisetup{detect-all,
    %input-ignore={.},
    group-separator = {.},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    input-decimal-markers={,}, 
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    table-alignment-mode=marker,
    table-number-alignment=center,
}

\begin{document}
    
    \hspace{5mm}
    \scalebox{0.63}{
    \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {Spá um raforkunotkun, forgangsorka og skerðanleg orka. Almenn notkun að meðtöldum dreifitöpum og núverandi og samþykktir nýir stórnotendur.},
        label = {table:Orkuspá},
        note{*} = {Rauntölur}]{
        colspec = {l *{10}{c}},
        hline{1,3,Z} = {1pt,solid},
        row{47-Z} = {font=\bfseries},
        row{1,3} = {abovesep=4pt},
        measure = vbox
        }
        \SetCell[r=2]{c,m} Ár & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Úttekt frá dreifikerfinu\newline forgangs- og skerðanleg\newline orka með dreifitöpum & & \SetCell[c=2]{c}Úttekt frá\newline flutningskerfinu & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Flutningstöp & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Úttekt frá\newline vinnslufyrirtækjum & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Samtals & \\
            & Orka \unit{GWh} & Afl \unit{MW} & Orka \unit{GWh} & Afl \unit{MW} & Orka \unit{GWh} & Afl \unit{MW} & Orka \unit{GWh} & Afl \unit{MW} & Orka \unit{GWh} & Afl \unit{MW}  \\
        2015 \TblrNote{*} & 3.604,74 & 618,46 & 14.356,34 & 1.685,89 & 369,56 & 57,11 & 468,32 & 75,40 & 18.798,96 & 2.383,25 \\
        2016 \TblrNote{*} & 3.383,99 & 590,10 & 14.334,19 & 1.695,96 & 360,42 & 57,05 & 470,86 & 71,46 & 18.549,46 & 2.378,51 \\
        2017 \TblrNote{*} & 3.519,13 & 608,86 & 14.869,95 & 1.750,87 & 373,07 & 61,49 & 476,38 & 84,74 & 19.238,53 & 2.443,61 \\
        2018 \TblrNote{*} & 3.682,07 & 623,26 & 15.259,88 & 1.838,28 & 398,09 & 70,47 & 489,75 & 70,71 & 19.829,79 & 2.519,53 \\
        2019 \TblrNote{*} & 3.506,86 & 596,63 & 15.145,31 & 1.829,48 & 365,82 & 63,40 & 476,84 & 85,11 & 19.494,83 & 2.495,07 \\
        2020 \TblrNote{*} & 3.473,77 & 596,83 & 14.830,70 & 1.790,95 & 353,09 & 60,54 & 469,74 & 72,27 & 19.127,30 & 2.408,28 \\
        2021 & 3.688,10 & 630,47 & 15.539,59 & 1.865,64 & 397,70 & 67,72 & 479,82 & 73,82 & 20.105,21 & 2.584,89 \\
        2022 & 3.785,98 & 647,81 & 16.099,28 & 1.875,76 & 416,40 & 69,68 & 490,14 & 75,41 & 20.791,80 & 2.615,29 \\
        2023 & 3.901,70 & 668,25 & 16.260,20 & 1.893,98 & 427,58 & 70,34 & 500,66 & 77,02 & 21.090,13 & 2.655,40 \\
        2024 & 3.991,75 & 684,32 & 16.325,85 & 1.899,97 & 436,37 & 70,59 & 511,28 & 78,66 & 21.265,25 & 2.678,87 \\
        2025 & 4.062,50 & 697,11 & 16.343,42 & 1.903,47 & 443,82 & 70,62 & 521,72 & 80,27 & 21.371,46 & 2.696,43 \\
        2026 & 4.122,77 & 708,12 & 16.343,42 & 1.903,47 & 450,61 & 70,54 & 526,76 & 81,04 & 21.443,55 & 2.707,91 \\
        2027 & 4.211,88 & 724,11 & 16.343,42 & 1.903,47 & 458,05 & 70,57 & 531,45 & 81,76 & 21.544,79 & 2.724,32 \\
        2028 & 4.296,04 & 739,29 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 465,42 & 70,58 & 536,08 & 82,47 & 21.640,51 & 2.739,90 \\
        2029 & 4.411,85 & 759,94 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 473,55 & 70,71 & 540,85 & 83,21 & 21.769,21 & 2.760,98 \\
        2030 & 4.532,38 & 781,44 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,86 & 70,86 & 545,67 & 83,95 & 21.902,87 & 2.782,93 \\
        2031 & 4.620,14 & 795,89 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,69 & 70,84 & 550,32 & 84,66 & 21.995,11 & 2.797,77 \\
        2032 & 4.717,78 & 812,01 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,73 & 70,84 & 555,02 & 85,39 & 22.097,48 & 2.814,28 \\
        2033 & 4.812,21 & 827,55 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,67 & 70,83 & 559,78 & 86,12 & 22.196,62 & 2.830,22 \\
        2034 & 4.902,86 & 842,42 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,51 & 70,81 & 564,68 & 86,87 & 22.292,01 & 2.845,50 \\
        2035 & 4.989,20 & 856,51 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,24 & 70,77 & 569,72 & 87,65 & 22.383,12 & 2.860,04 \\
        2036 & 5.072,75 & 870,11 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 480,89 & 70,72 & 574,87 & 88,44 & 22.471,48 & 2.874,09 \\
        2037 & 5.152,14 & 882,97 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 480,43 & 70,65 & 580,05 & 89,24 & 22.555,59 & 2.887,41 \\
        2038 & 5.228,32 & 895,26 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,89 & 70,57 & 585,32 & 90,05 & 22.636,49 & 2.900,17 \\
        2039 & 5.302,08 & 907,11 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,29 & 70,48 & 590,68 & 90,87 & 22.715,00 & 2.912,50 \\
        2040 & 5.405,41 & 924,00 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,30 & 70,49 & 596,13 & 91,71 & 22.823,81 & 2.929,88 \\
        2041 & 5.478,79 & 935,75 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 478,65 & 70,39 & 601,62 & 92,56 & 22.902,03 & 2.942,12 \\
        2042 & 5.552,10 & 947,46 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 477,99 & 70,29 & 607,11 & 93,40 & 22.980,15 & 2.954,33 \\
        2043 & 5.626,68 & 959,37 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 477,33 & 70,20 & 612,60 & 94,25 & 23.059,57 & 2.966,73 \\
        2044 & 5.703,24 & 971,59 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 476,71 & 70,10 & 618,20 & 95,11 & 23.141,10 & 2.979,47 \\
        2045 & 5.782,58 & 984,27 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 476,12 & 70,02 & 623,90 & 95,98 & 23.225,56 & 2.992,67 \\
        2046 & 5.864,53 & 997,37 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 475,58 & 69,94 & 629,65 & 96,87 & 23.312,72 & 3.006,30 \\
        2047 & 5.948,06 & 1.010,72 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 475,05 & 69,86 & 635,38 & 97,75 & 23.401,45 & 3.020,16 \\
        2048 & 6.033,38 & 1.024,34 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 474,54 & 69,79 & 641,24 & 98,65 & 23.492,13 & 3.034,33 \\
        2049 & 6.119,59 & 1.038,10 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 474,03 & 69,71 & 647,11 & 99,56 & 23.583,69 & 3.048,62 \\
        2050 & 6.207,13 & 1.052,06 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 473,53 & 69,64 & 653,00 & 100,46 & 23.676,62 & 3.063,11 \\
        2051 & 6.298,36 & 1.067,52 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 475,50 & 69,93 & 658,16 & 101,26 & 23.774,98 & 3.079,33 \\
        2052 & 6.389,36 & 1.082,94 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 477,46 & 70,22 & 663,38 & 102,06 & 23.873,16 & 3.095,51 \\
        2053 & 6.479,88 & 1.098,29 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 479,42 & 70,50 & 668,64 & 102,87 & 23.970,91 & 3.111,63 \\
        2054 & 6.569,42 & 1.113,46 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 481,35 & 70,79 & 673,96 & 103,69 & 24.067,70 & 3.127,58 \\
        2055 & 6.657,82 & 1.128,44 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 483,27 & 71,07 & 679,34 & 104,51 & 24.163,39 & 3.143,35 \\
        2056 & 6.744,86 & 1.143,20 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 485,15 & 71,35 & 684,76 & 105,35 & 24.257,74 & 3.158,90 \\
        2057 & 6.830,19 & 1.157,66 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 487,01 & 71,62 & 690,25 & 106,19 & 24.350,41 & 3.174,16 \\
        2058 & 6.913,30 & 1.171,75 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 488,82 & 71,88 & 695,78 & 107,04 & 24.440,86 & 3.189,06 \\
        2059 & 6.993,67 & 1.185,37 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 490,57 & 72,14 & 701,37 & 107,90 & 24.528,57 & 3.203,51 \\
        2060 & 7.071,89 & 1.198,63 & 16.342,96 & 1.903,47 & 492,28 & 72,39 & 707,02 & 108,77 & 24.614,16 & 3.217,60 \\
        2061 & 7.172,96 & 1.214,87 & 16.398,49 & 1.907,18 & 496,07 & 71,07 & 712,49 & 109,61 & 24.780,01 & 3.236,67\\
        2062 & 7.258,87 & 1.229,10 & 16.402,60 & 1.907,46 & 497,27 & 71,09 & 717,97 & 110,46 & 24.876,71 & 3.251,74\\
        2063 & 7.344,78 & 1.243,34 & 16.406,71 & 1.907,73 & 498,47 & 71,12 & 723,45 & 111,30 & 24.973,41 & 3.266,82\\
        2064 & 7.430,69 & 1.257,57 & 16.410,81 & 1.908,01 & 499,67 & 71,14 & 728,94 & 112,14 & 25.070,11 & 3.281,89\\
        2065 & 7.516,60 & 1.271,80 & 16.414,92 & 1.908,29 & 500,87 & 71,17 & 734,42 & 112,99 & 25.166,80 & 3.296,96\\
        2066 & 7.602,51 & 1.286,04 & 16.419,02 & 1.908,56 & 502,07 & 71,20 & 739,90 & 113,83 & 25.263,50 & 3.312,04\\
        2067 & 7.688,41 & 1.300,27 & 16.423,13 & 1.908,84 & 503,27 & 71,22 & 745,39 & 114,67 & 25.360,20 & 3.327,11\\
        2068 & 7.772,08 & 1.313,81 & 16.395,02 & 1.907,70 & 502,13 & 71,14 & 750,25 & 115,42 & 25.456,90  & 3.342,18\\
        2069 & 7.855,96 & 1.327,38 & 16.387,86 & 1.906,81 & 501,46 & 71,14 & 755,25 & 116,19 & 25.553,60 & 3.357,25\\
        2070 & 7.940,94 & 1.341,16 & 16.386,68 & 1.906,59 & 500,99 & 71,16 & 760,41 & 116,99 & 25.650,29 & 3.372,33\\
        2071 & 8.026,03 & 1.354,96 & 16.388,08 & 1.906,60 & 500,68 & 71,19 & 765,78 & 117,81 & 25.746,99 & 3.387,40
    \end{longtblr}
    \end{minipage}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** in the chat room the issue has been discussed some further. Several tables contained currency columns. In order to correctly align the currency symbol and the values inside the columns, the setup of `siunitx` had to be changed to:

```
\sisetup{detect-all,
    group-separator = {.},
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
}
```

This change does NOT affect the rendering of the table in this answer.

Comment: There was package missing, thanks to @alchemist and DaiBowen we figured it out.