# Using \fontseries{b}\selectfont does not give me a bold face

Tags: fonts, bold

I am trying to emulate the font below:

[image]

Apparently it can be done with:

```
\renewcommand*{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}
```

This is from the [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) package, more specifically the file [`moderncvstyleclassic.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstyleclassic.sty)

In my case, I thought I could get it with:

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont This is a test}
```

But it doesn't work. Instead I get:

[image]

which by the way is also what I get with:

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{m}\selectfont This is a test}
```

Notice that the difference between both code snippets is using `\fontseries{b}` instead of `\fontseries{m}`

With this:

- How can I get the font in the first image?
- Why is it that `\fontseries{b}` and `\fontseries{m}` yield the same result above?

## Update 1:

If I use

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{bx}\selectfont This is a test}
```

I get:

[image]

which is still different from what I show in the top image.

Comment: Isn't it `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont`?

Comment: @cgnieder: I think this can be an answer if elaborated.

Comment: @cgnieder, I have updated my post. Using `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont` is not doing the trick.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov I actually don't know enough about fonts to elaborate much on this. A quick look into the [fntguide](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) told me that `b` also is a common font series.

Comment: @intrpc I don't understand. Your edit show that `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont` _works_ if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @cgnieder, using  `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont` gives a result different from the font that I am trying to emulate (shown in the top image).

Comment: OK. Where did you get the first image from? Do you have access to the source/the PDF?

Comment: @AndreyVihrov I have updated the information in the post regarding the source of the image.

Comment: You're another victim of `cm-super` without `fix-cm`. Loading `fix-cm`, switching to `lmodern` or removing `T1` (which has other downsides) fixes the problem (but affects the whole document), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1396/1340.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lmss` instead of `cmss`:

[image: result of lmss vs. result of cmss]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{red}\tiny\ttfamily lmss}\smallbreak
{\fontsize{34}{36}\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmss}\fontseries{m}\selectfont This is a test}

{\color{red}\tiny\ttfamily cmss}\smallbreak
{\fontsize{34}{36}\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{m}\selectfont This is a test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`b` isn't that common, bold fonts are normally extended, which would be `bx` although some font packages define `b` to alias to `bx` so either work. cmss *does* have another bold font in addition to the usual extended one but it is *condensed* compared to the normal weight font.

The Standard LaTeX fd files declare this variant as `sbc` although in my (texlive 2010) setup the font only seems to be available as metafont rather than as a scalable font, however

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}


\sf

This is a Test

\fontseries{bx}\selectfont

This is a Test

\fontseries{sbc}\selectfont

This is a Test

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: If you look close, the semibold condensed variant still isn't what is pictured on the first image (note that `sbc` has round edges). Latin Modern's equivalent also won't do. So I am at loss in telling what is on the image, although it is a Computer Modern variant for sure.

Comment: Yes true, The original didn't look condensed either. My main intention was to explain why `b` did nothing is that it's not in the fd file, and for cmss the only bold variants declared in the fd are bx and sbc.

Answer (score 1):

You should tell us which font you are using. However, not all sans serif fonts have a bold version. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\Huge
This is a test

\sffamily\bfseries
This is a test

\end{document}
```

[image]