# What's the difference between ngerman and german in babel?

Tags: languages, babel

I use the following three packages to get correct German umlauts in the generated PDF:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
```

Today, I have seen this:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

What's the difference between `ngerman` and `german`? I think `n` could probably mean new, but which one should I use? Do you have an example where it matters?

Comment: To be precise, `inputenc` makes sure the umlauts etc. in the source are read correctly; `babel` makes sure the correct hyphenation patterns are used and changes the language of text strings like *Table of Contents*; `fontenc` changes the font encoding in the PDF, otherwise an `ä` would be created as a combination of `a` and `¨`, which looks worse and makes copy-paste harder. For my "German" setup, I usually also use `lmodern` (Latin Modern) as a font (the alternative is installing the `cm-super` package, which is then automatically used by `fontenc`), cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65103.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As has been said before, `german` is *Alte Rechtschreibung* (= "right-writing" = orthography = "right-writing"), `ngerman` is *Neue Rechtschreibung*. The part that's really relevant is hyphenation, because that's what `babel` influences. So here are some examples what has changed in hyphenation, taken from [canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Reform/Worttrennung/index.html) (I'm strongly assuming that `babel` implemented these changes, but I didn't check the code):

```
old         new
Braue-rei   Brau-e-rei
Bäk-ker     Bä-cker     ← This is imho the most important change, which can easily be spotted
Mei-ster    Meis-ter
```

While changes like old *Schiffahrt* to new *Schifffahrt* are correct, they're not really relevant from `babel`'s point of view because `babel` doesn't correct your spelling, so that's really up to you, i.e. it depends on what you type. As always with such conventions, you should be consistent in your choice of orthography. Officially, *Alte Rechtschreibung* has been deprecated for a few years; before that, both were "allowed".

Comment: My line of thought was that babel probably wouldn't recognize "Schifffahrt" and simply wouldn't hyphenate it.

Comment: @JuriRobl: That would make sense, but is actually not the case: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} \setlength{\textwidth}{.5cm} \begin{document}x Schiffahrt \par x Schifffahrt\end{document}` (The `x` are necessary because the first word in a paragraph won't be hyphenated) -- both are hyphenated, no matter which one of `german` and `ngerman` I use.

Answer (score 17):

As said before `german` refers to "Alte Rechtschreibung", the orthography before 2006, and `ngerman` to "Neue Rechtschreibung", the orthography since 2006 (with transition period since 1996). Thus the differences are:

- Different hyphenation patterns are used due to changed rules in hyphenation.
  In case of `ngerman` babel loads hyphenation pattern, that are derived from the
  old patterns by Walter Schmidt.

  BTW, there are newer experimental patterns, see [`dehyph-exptl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dehyph-exptl). They can be made available using package [`hyphsubst`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyphsubst).
- Some of the hyphenation rules have changed. In the old orthography `ck` was hyphenated
  as `k-k`. Or triple consonants are avoided if followed by vowels, but the third consonants reappeared if hyphenated, e.g.:

  Schiffahrt → Schiff-fahrt

  In `german` this was supported by shorthands:

  ```
  B"a"cker Schi"ffahrt
  ```

  Because these cases are simplified in the new orthography, these special shorthands
  are no longer available in `ngerman`:

  ```
    "c, "C, "f, "F, "l, "L, "m, "M, "n, "N, "p, "P, "r, "R, "t", "T
  ```

  Also macro `\ck` has been dropped for the same reason.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the `n` stands for new, as it is the "neue deutsche Rechtschreibung" from (in the current form) 2006. One of the most common differences is the different use of 'ß' and 'ss'. As it is the current one, you should always use `ngerman`.

One example is "Schifffahrt" (new) in contrast to the old "Schiffahrt", as triple consonants at the joint of compound words used to be reduced to only two.

Comment: What does babel do different with `Schifffahrt` and `Schiffahrt`? I mean, it doesn't autocorrect, does it? - I've just seen that doncherry mentioned hyphenation.

Comment: I figured that it couldn't recognize it as a word it knows, and wouldn't hyphenate it. I was wrong though, as doncherry pointed out in his comment.