# Cannot input utf8 encoding with csvreader

Tags: tables, unicode, input, csvsimple

I am trying to generate a table with `\csvreader`. The problem is latex is ignoring when I have some german chars such as; `ü`,`ä`,`ö`

How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
LO-üäo-OK,TH-uao-IS,100
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
    table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline]%
{scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
{\thecsvrow & \name~\surname & \age}%
\end{document}
```

The Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Just for fun, is the generated csv encoded correctly? Does it work if you use datatool instead of csvsimple

Comment: If I compile your MWE on my system, I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGpKE.png

Comment: Regarding the `babel` option ou have chosen, you might want to have a look at [https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGpKE.png](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67549/134144)

Comment: don't test your original file, copy the code above and test it as a new file [you should get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EQ7Z.png)