# Undesirable text alignment with 'parallel' package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, parallel

I have been working on a document that has a German text on the left and a vocab list on the right, which involves dividing the document into two columns. The tool of choice is 'parallel' package ( https://ctan.org/pkg/parallel ), since the vocab list has to be parallel with the corresponding paragraph of the German text. Although the package does enable me that, there are some problems with text alignment that I would like to eliminate.

PROBLEM 1: Each paragraph of the right column has an indent, which I don't want! (Note that I double-spaced each of the entries in the right column, so each 'word' is treated as a paragraph.)

[image: EXHIBIT 1]

```
\ParallelLText{

\textbf{Die chinesische Militärführung \uline{lädt} Afrikas Armeechefs nach Peking \uline{ein} - offiziell um \uline{Friedenseinsätze} zu diskutieren. Doch China \uline{verfolgt} mit seiner Militärstrategie in Afrika noch ganz andere Ziele, sagen Experten.}

}

\ParallelRText{

einladen: to invite

Friedenseinsatz: peacekeeping operation

verfolgen: to pursue

}

\ParallelPar

\pp
```

PROBLEM 2: Sometimes the package produces unexpected (for the lack of better word) result.

[image: EXHIBIT 2]

```
\LR{\paragraph{Ziel: Wirtschaftsinteressen sichern} China \uline{ginge} es vor allem darum, seine Präsenz in Afrika verstärken, so Benabdallah. Etwa durch eine stärkere Zusammenarbeit mit der Afrikanischen Union, durch mehr Polizei- und Militärtrainings und mehr Friedenssoldaten. Dabei spiele auch die Militärbasis in Dschibuti eine zentrale Rolle. }
{ginge: first-and-third singular past subjunctive of gehen
}
```

where the command 'LR' is defined as

```
\newcommand\LR[2]{\ParallelLText{#1}\ParallelRText{#2}\ParallelPar\pp}
\newcommand\pp[0]{\endgraf\vspace{12pt}}
```

(Problem 2 is what annoys me most!)

For your information here is a part of the code including the preamble and the problematic part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{kotex} %typesets Korean text
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\pp[0]{\endgraf\vspace{12pt}}

\newcommand\LR[2]{\ParallelLText{#1}\ParallelRText{#2}\ParallelPar\pp}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{.55\linewidth}{.4\linewidth}

\ParallelLText{

\textbf{Die chinesische Militärführung \uline{lädt} Afrikas Armeechefs nach Peking \uline{ein} - offiziell um \uline{Friedenseinsätze} zu diskutieren. Doch China \uline{verfolgt} mit seiner Militärstrategie in Afrika noch ganz andere Ziele, sagen Experten.}

}

\ParallelRText{

einladen: to invite

Friedenseinsatz: peacekeeping operation

verfolgen: to pursue

}

\ParallelPar

\pp

\end{Parallel}

%other parts of document%

\begin{Parallel}{.55\linewidth}{.4\linewidth}

\LR{\paragraph{Ziel: Wirtschaftsinteressen sichern} China \uline{ginge} es vor allem darum, seine Präsenz in Afrika verstärken, so Benabdallah. Etwa durch eine stärkere Zusammenarbeit mit der Afrikanischen Union, durch mehr Polizei- und Militärtrainings und mehr Friedenssoldaten. Dabei spiele auch die Militärbasis in Dschibuti eine zentrale Rolle. }
{ginge: first-and-third singular past subjunctive of gehen
}

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for reading this!

**UPDATE: The second problem has something to do with \paragraph command. If I delete \paragraph{Ziel: Wirtschaftsinteressen sichern} the problem disappears. However, I really do not want to sacrifice the title of the paragraph to fix this issue. Is there any possible workaround?**

p.s. The 'LR' macro is not my original work. The original source is here: https://bitbucket.org/dpb/parallel_vocabulary_list/src/default/parallel_vocabulary_list.tex

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but you probably might want to replace `[german]` by `[ngerman]` as the former refers to the old orthography rules. For more information on this, you can have a look here: [What's the difference between ngerman and german in babel?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67549/134144)

Comment: I am more familiar with paracol (newer and IMHO better).  There one can only switch columns between paragraphs, and I suspect parallel is the same.  You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413580/how-to-correctly-change-the-side-that-marginpar-appears-per-case/414186?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.1542#414186 interesting.

Comment: Never knew that Babel had separate options for the new orthography rules! I learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

It's embarassing to post an answer to my own question, but I finally found a way around problem 2. As John mentioned in his comment, paracol produces more reliable outcome than parallel. Here is a recipe for my 'LR' command written w/ paracol, for those who are interested in:

```
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand\pp[0]{\endgraf\vspace{12pt}}

\newcommand\LR[2]{\switchcolumn[0]* %
    #1
    \switchcolumn %
    #2
    \pp}

\begin{document}

\section{Noch immer große regionale Unterschiede}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\LR{\textbf{Das Armutsrisiko in Deutschland ist regional sehr unterschiedlich verteilt. Aber eine neue Statistik zeigt: Ost und West nähern sich an.}
}
{
\begin{itemize}
    \item verteilen
    \item sich annähern
\end{itemize}
}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

The code above produces this:
[image]

For those who are forced to use parallel for some reason, the issue related with \paragraph{} command can be 'fixed' by substituting it with \textbf{}. A fix that is hardly satisfying but nonetheless still looks decent in the eye.