# Latex doesn't break line - line goes into border area

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

In my document I have several lines where the words are not wrapped to the next line. Latex writes it into the border area of the page.

I can not reproduce it in an MWE. There it is working correctly.

Maybe this a typical behavior and someone knows how to fix it.

It seems that it happens when the word has a hyphen. Is there a simple option to make those words wrap?

Here are screenshots:

1.

[image]
2.

[image]
3.

[image]
4.

[image]

Comment: Could be this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63232/why-can-words-with-hyphen-char-not-be-hyphenated/63234#63234 ?

Comment: And probably the easier solution is @loop-space https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2715/38080

Comment: I replaced al hyphens by `"=` and now it works as expected. But I still don't understand why is is needed and doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: I'm happy it works for you. The reason is deep ingrained in the original TeX engine, see the answer by @egreg in the first question I linked.

Comment: You have probably seen "hbox overfull" warning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
\usepackage[language]{babel}
```

in your preamble? Remember that *language* should be the language in which you are writing your document.

With respect to that, take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67549/whats-the-difference-between-ngerman-and-german-in-babel) page, where they discuss the differences between *german* and *ngerman* option in the Babel package, which might be relevant for hyphenation.