# Bold and italic not working in math

Tags: bold, italic

I am trying to get this little matrix to work but I cant seem to find a way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \label{eg:Verstärkungsmatrix}
    \bm{\Bar{K}}_s &= 
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
            454.8000 & 8.8000 \\
            -44.8800 & 2.1200
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The problem happens if I want to add `\bm` and `\bar` at the same time. Each on their on work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes I stripped the code I am using. I cant seem to find the reason its not working.

Comment: `german` is obsolete. Do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but the error is caused by the use of the `german` package. If you remove that package, it works. You can also circumvent the error by switching the `\bar` and `\bm` commands.

This:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    \label{eg:Verstärkungsmatrix}
    \Bar{\bm{K}}_s &= 
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    454.8000 & 8.8000 \\
    -44.8800 & 2.1200
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

gives this:[image]

which is not exactly what you want but it may be close enough?

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to remove `\usepackage{german}` either way. Nowadays one should prefer `babel` (`\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` - `ngerman` für *Neue Rechtschreibung*, `german` for pre-1996 *alte Rechtschreibung*, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67549/35864) or `polyglossia` over `german`. Not all modern packages are compatible with `\usepackage{german}`, but they usually work together with `babel` or `polyglossia` (I'm thinking `biblatex` and `csquotes`).