# Make pdflatex output UTF-8 copy-pasteable when using Times font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, copy-paste, times

I would like to use **Adobe Times Roman font** or its equivalent (like URW Nimbus Roman and fonts based on it), compiling with `pdflatex` to PDF -- the original intent was to have PDF smaller by using built-in fonts.  The document in question is in Polish, and uses UTF-8 input encoding. I would like the PDF to be ***copy-and-pasteable*** with **result in UTF-8**, for both roman family and typewriter family (for code listing).

Unfortunately neither of solutions in [What are good ways to make pdflatex output copy-and-pasteable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64188/5886) works, at least not with `\usepackage{times}` as a way to switch to Roman-like font.

Take an example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
%\usepackage{cmap}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\rmfamily
rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń \\
\ttfamily
ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń \\
\end{document}
```

The result is not an unrecognizable mess of symbols as was in [Can't copy-paste from my PDF. Any idea why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72900/5886), but some of Polish characters are copied in a strange way, as if precomposed: with base character and accent (decoration) separate... and either of them can be out of text flow.

For the example document the `pdftotext` result (and copy'n'paste result) is:

```
˙ c e ˛ z´
rmfamily: zazół´ g˛ sia ja´ n
ttfamily: za˙ół´ g˛sia ja´´
z c e ˛
zn

1
```

If I switch from `times` to `lmodern` (Latin Modern font), and presumably also when switching to `cm-super` I get the correct result:

```
rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń
ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń

1
```

Comment: First time I've seen this without the brackets around `glyphtounicode`. AFAIK it's a file and thus it should be `{glyphtounicode}`.

Comment: @henry If I use `\input{glyphtounicode}`, my [code below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239177/9077) won't work anymore. The copy-and-past will be gobbled.

Comment: @Sverre ... woah. That is the first time I read of this happening so either something is not working right and/or I am way out of my depth here. Seeing how you and egreg talking about this, the latter is certainly true.

Comment: @Sverre Alright, I have searched for `glyphtounicode.tex` on my OS and it is definitely a file... at least in the way I use it.

Comment: @henry I'm as puzzled as you are. This hasn't made a difference for me before, but for some reason it does here. I might open a separate question about it.

Comment: Btw: It's 2015 and we have XeTeX and LuaTeX: No need to use pdfTeX with Unicode anymore, use engines that support Unicode directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Times font `TeX Gyre Termes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
\noindent
\rmfamily
rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń \\
\ttfamily
ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Copy and paste from the `.pdf` gives this result:

```
rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń
ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń
```

Comment: Or `newtxtext` and the accompanying `newtxmath` for math symbols.

Comment: @egreg If I use `newtxtext`, I get this when I copy-and-paste from the `.pdf`: `zażółć g˛esi˛a jaźń`. It doesn't cope with the ogonek glyphs, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Sverre's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239177/5886) of using TeX Gyre Termes (`tgtermes` package): it doesn't work for me with `\ttfamily` / `\texttt{}` i.e. typewriter fonts.  I get the following from `pdftotext` (version 0.12.4):

```
rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń
ttfamily: za»óª¢ g¦si¡ ja¹«
```

I have browsed [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html) and found out the following solution -- use [TXTT font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/txtt/) for ttfamily with **`\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}`**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tgtermes}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
\noindent
\rmfamily
rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń \\
\ttfamily
ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to be using an extremely old version of [`pdftotext`](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html), since the current version is `3.04`. Running `pdftotext -enc UTF-8 [PDF-file]` on the output file of [my code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239177/5886) gives me `rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń`.

Comment: @Sverre: When using evince 3.10.3 copy'n'paste gives me without TXTT: `rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń
tt❢❛♠✐❧2✿ 3❛➺ó➟➣ ❣➛s✐→ ❥❛➵➠`

Comment: Copy-and-paste from my output file with `evince` gives me ``rmfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń
ttfamily: zażółć gęsią jaźń``. You may want to update your TeX packages or something.