# exported PDFs are different in windows and ubuntu

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, windows, ubuntu

I am using Texmaker with PDFLaTeX build option in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. The `.tex` uses my institute's template which is said "using scrreprt class of KOMA-Script".

The problem is: I can copy and paste the content of the PDF file which is created in Windows normally, while the copied content of the PDF file which is created in Ubuntu is just a combination of special characters, for example `❲✐♥❞♦✇s P❧❛tt❢♦r♠` instead of `Windows Plattform`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

Windows Plattform

\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

`pdffonts test.pdf` results:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       4  0
```

About `\usepackage{t1enc}`: I don't know, since it comes from my institute's template and my supervisor just told me to modify the template as less as possible. There is just a comment `% dc-Fonts` following that package.

Comment: On Ubuntu, what do you get when you use the command (in a terminal) `pdffonts myfile.pdf` (where 'myfile' is the name of the PDF where you see this problem)?  Also please remove `\usepackage{t1enc}` before compiling. Why do you have that there?

Comment: Ah, Type 3. Avoid 'em!  Either install `cm-super` or use a different font. `\usepackage{lmodern}` is a 'modern' but nearly identical font to the default you are using. Also skip the `\usepackage{t1enc}`: you are doing enough with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you should be able to do `sudo apt-get install cm-super` if you installed your 'TeX system' from the Debian repositories on which Ubuntu depends.

Comment: I am working on the `.tex` file parallel between Ubuntu and Windows (on lab and at home, commit changes via SVN). Does using `cm-super` on Ubuntu (or `\usepackage{lmodern}` as you said) make any difference between the PDFs exported by each machine?

Comment: You'd have to investigate the PDF produced on the Windows machine. I don't have Windows, so I can't check what is happening. The problem on the Ubuntu side looks like it is that you are using Type 3 fonts (by accident). If so, the solution is to stop using Type 3 fonts. However, if both files use the same font package and are produced with the same way (say, by using `pdflatex`), then there shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, regardless of the Windows world, on Ubuntu, you should install `cm-super` (and I doubt the PDFs b/w the two computers will be appreciably different afterwards).

Comment: seems `\usepackage{lmodern}` has solved my problem ... I will try with `cm-super` later, thank you

Comment: OK, seems like this may be a duplicate, then: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72900/8528

Comment: It's quite strange since I tried with Macbook today, Macbook can copy and paste the content of PDF created in Ubuntu totally normal (haven't used `lmodern` or `cm-super` in Ubuntu yet).

Comment: Apparently, your supervisor doesn't have a good LaTeX knowledge. Please make him aware that the template needs some updates. This kind of thing (outdated templates) happens often and is the cause of about 10 percent of the questions here.

Comment: Feel free to lok at golatex.de or texwelt.de if you want.

Comment: I would suggest that you install `cm-super` regardless of whether it does or seems to help with this problem (it will then be used whenever you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but don't also load a specific font package). As to whether you should use `cm-super` or `lmodern`, [the answers here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390/8528) are worth reading.

Comment: Is there any news here?