# Writing in Greek, but can't copy Greek?

Tags: code, greek, copy-paste

So, I have a file in Gree, with some English letters. Everything works fine, no syntactic errors or anything. When I go into the PDF to copy from it or search for something, it never returns my query. When I try to copy something from the said PDF, it doesn't copy Greek characters, it copies English non-sense.

For example, I want to copy (Greek) "*μικροσωληνίσκοι ενώνονται με τα κεντρομερίδια των χρωμοσωμάτων*" and my clipboard gets "*mikroswlhnÐskoi en¸nontai me ta kentromerÐdia twn qrwmoswmˆtwn*".

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT:*** Software: I'm using TeXworks on "pdfLaTeX" to write LaTeX and Adobe Acrobat to view PDF's.

CODE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}     % Very nice margin setup
\usepackage{braket}     % Used for maths
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}    % Math stuff


\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}  % Setup for hyperlink Package from here  ...
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DeepPink4}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DarkRed}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=DarkBlue}  % ... to here

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\bd}{\textbf}   % Creating a custom command to help ust



\begin{document}

\title{\bd{ΜΙΤΩΣΗ{}}} % Bold title
\maketitle





{\selectlanguage{greek} \underline{\bd{Πρόφαση:}}  \textit{(Mεγαλύτερο σε διάρκεια στάδιο της μείωσης.)} \\   (1)  Iνίδια χρωματίνης \bd{$\rightarrow$} συμπυκνώνονται και παίρνουν μορφή χρωμοσωμάτων.  ένα χρωμόσωμα Αποτελείται από δύο πανομοιότυπες αδελφές χρωματίδες που ενώνονται στο κεντρομερίδιο. \\ \\ Γιατί χρωμοσώματα?\\  

Για να μη σπάσει ούτε χαθεί τίποτε από τη μεταφορά του γενετικού υλικού στα θυγατρικά κύτταρα.  \\


(2) Σχηματισμός \bd{Ατράκτου} $\rightarrow$ μέσω του αναδιπλασιασμένου (από το στάδιο {\selectlanguage{english}\bd{G2}} της μεσόφασης) κεντροσωμάτιου. Τα 2 κεντροσωμάτια μετακινούνται προς τους 2 πόλους και προβάλονται \underline{ακτινωτά νημάτια}, οι \bd{μικροσωληνίσκοι}, που σχηματίζουν την άτρακτο. \\ 

(3) Οι μικροσωληνίσκοι ενώνονται με τα κεντρομερίδια των χρωμοσωμάτων, μετά την αποχώρηση του πυρηνικού φακέλου και του πυρινήσκου.} \\ \\

{\selectlanguage{greek} \underline{\bd{Μετάφαση:}}  \\(1) Τα χρωμοσώματα αρχίζουν και μετακινούνται από τις τυχαίες θέσεις τους, προς το Ισημερινό Επίπεδο του κυττάρου.  \\

(2) Τα κεντρομερίδια έχουν φτάσει στο ισημερινό επίπεδο και οι χρωματίδες (κάθε χρωμοσώματος) παράλληλα προς αυτό. \\

(3) Στη μετάφαση συνεχίζεται η συμπίκνωση της χρωματίνης. Στο τέλος, τα χρωμοσώματα έχουν το μέγιστο βαθμό συμπύκνωσης (και είναι διακριτά). Άρα, η παρατήρηση και φωτογράφισή τους γίνεται σε αυτό το στάδιο.}  \\ \\

{\selectlanguage{greek} \underline{\bd{Ανάφαση:}} \\ Το κεντρομερίδιο κάθε χρωμοσώματος διαιρείται. Οι μικροσωληνίσκοι ασκούν αντίθετη έλξη στα κεντρομερίδια και έτσι οι 2 αδελφές χρωματίδες κινούνται στον αντίθετο πόλο η κάθε μία, σαν να κινούνται πάνω σε ράγες τρένου.}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried to change pdf editor? Or to change font? I think one of these options will work... In other case just use XeLaTeX ...

Comment: it copies fine for me. Is your tex system up-to-date? If not you should load and activate glyphtounicode.

Comment: Also see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72904/120578

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Any software suggestions? I've been using TexWorks for a while and I like the pdf-preview thingy (I'm guessing every editor have that) but I think I should transition..

Comment: I didn't say that you should change your software. But your document perhaps need a change, if the pdf doesn't contain the correct ToUnicode values copy&paste can't work. Search for glyphtounicode on the site here.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering my question because I have since found a solution:*

I added this to my preamble:

```latex
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

This made it copy *(understnad?)* Greek letters.