# Broken display of 11pt typewriter text in Acrobat Reader

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontsize, typewriter, acrobat

I set some all-caps words in my document as typewriter. Using `scrartcl` as documentclass, with a default fontsize of 11pt, yields a PDF that looks rather bad in Acrobat Reader. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\texttt{FOO\_BAR}
\end{document}
```

When using another documentclass like `article` or with documentclass `scrartcl` and the option `[fontsize=10pt]` everything renders fine. I tested Acrobat Reader 11 on MacOS Lion and Version 9 on Windows XP. On the other hand, using e.g. MacOS Preview or Skim as PDF viewers, even the original version with fontsize 11pt renders fine.

**[Update]** Here is a screenshot of the rendering in Acrobat Reader 11 on MacOS Lion:

[image]

and a screenshot from the rendering in MacOS Preview:

[image]

Here you can see that e.g. the letters F and R in Acrobat are not as high as the other letters, in contrast to the rendering of Preview (or when using a fontsize of 10pt or 12pt).

**[Update]** This is not a duplicate of [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically). In my example you can see, that I already use modern and I just checked, that Acrobat really says that Type 1 fonts are used. So I have no problems with bitmap/Type3 fonts.

Is there any way to make those typewriter texts look good in Acrobat Reader with size 11pt?

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of how it looks bad in AR?

Comment: Looks fine on my computer, with Adobe Reader XI.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. But I fail to see how the first screenshot is bad. The TT font has a pixely look but that's just how the font looks.

Comment: This is IMHO a duplicate of [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98410/why-does-latin-modern-make-strange-appearing-output](Why does Latin Modern make strange-appearing output?), which is marked as a duplicate of [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super](Latin Modern vs cm-super?). The issue is in the (in my opinion) not perfect hinting of `lmodern` font.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate of [Why does Latin Modern make strange-appearing output?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98410/why-does-latin-modern-make-strange-appearing-output) (thanks to tohecz for the link). The best workarounds seem to be using another fontsize like 10pt or 12pt or using another font (like the BlueSky Computer Modern variant).